# set typeface of text view to Typeface.NORMAL doesn't have any effect, why?

Tags: android, expandablelistview, android-typeface

I have listeners for [ExpandableListView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html) for group collapsed and expanded:

```
// There is a text view on group layout, no problem there.
    @Override
    public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
        // this callback is triggered, however, once the textView is BOLD by onGroupExpanded, the textView is not set back to normal, seems this line of code does nothing...WHY?
        textView.setTypeface(textView.getTypeface(), Typeface.NORMAL);
    }

    @Override
    public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
        // it works fine
        textView.setTypeface(textView.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);
    }
```

As you can see above, I have a `textView` in group layout, when group is expanded, I **bold** the `textView`, if collapsed, I try to set it back to **unbold** by `Typeface.NORMAL`.

**Both callbacks are triggered correctly**, however, once the `textView` is **BOLD** by `onGroupExpanded(...)` callback, the `textView` is not set back to NORMAL when `onGroupCollapse(...)` is triggered afterwards. Seems the line of code in `onGroupCollapsed(...)`does nothing...WHY?

(Again, `onGroupCollapse(...)` is triggered. No problem there!)

Comment: try `textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);` how does it look?

Comment: @donfuxx,  It works now after I did the change you suggested. But could you please also explain why my code has that issue? why use null as the first parameter solves the issue?

Comment: I tried to explain in my answer ;-) I know the setTypeface method is not really intuitive and confuses myself from time to time :-P

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
```

you need to put null to drop the other typefaces (in your case Bold). How I understand it one text view can have multiple typesfaces, like for example italic+bold etc. and the first parameter is to indicate if you want to keep those or not. So basically your previous code kept BOLD and added NORMAL, and BOLD won ;-)

see also related answer and comments here https://stackoverflow.com/a/6200841/2399024

Comment: Honest...Thanks for the ref.

Comment: it will work but will reset text appearance (font family and so on)

Answer (score 37):

If you use `android:fontFamily` on this TextView then I am pretty sure

```
textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
```

will change to the default font. Another way to do this is:

```
textView.setTypeface(Typeface.create(textView.getTypeface(), Typeface.NORMAL));
```

The original problem is that TextView's `setTypeface` with the style oddly skips over some stuff if the style is NORMAL. I've tested this on one version, and it works.

Comment: Yes, you are right. That should be the accepted answer.

Comment: won't be able to set NORMAL after ITALIC or BOLD