# How do you set Bold style for specific word in android?

Tags: java, android

I already know how we can do that, but those are not for my use. I want it just within set text without creating any new string in java. I found many questions already on stackoverflow, But they all are different for me in this case.

**Here what i've tried :**

```
printResult.setText(String.valueOf(Html.fromHtml("<b>" +printNumbers+ "</b>" )));
```

Comment: Does this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6200841/11023871) provide the information you have requested? From what I understand, it's just a simple `TextView` (with all the characters bolded), so this should be sufficient

Comment: No, that's not what i'm looking for. That will be for all text. I need just for a specific word as i printed above in my code that is `printNumbers`

Comment: You can use a [`StyleSpan`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/StyleSpan) for that.

Answer (score 0):

The method `String.valueOf()` will convert the `Spannable` to `String` and your formatted string will lost. So, remove the `String.valueOf()` method and use below code:

```
printResult.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>" +printNumbers+ "</b>" ));
```

Comment: I've tried what you asked to do. But bad luck it's not working .

Comment: have you fixed issue?

Comment: Not yet. Still looking for a answer.

Comment: `<TextView
            android:id="@+id/loneresult"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:gravity="center"/>`

Comment: This Id is loneresult but you are trying to set bold for printResult