# How to have a string Bold into a textView with Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to have a string Bold into a textView with Kotlin, here's my code :

```
 val priceTxt = "10.000" ///example
    
    val s = SpannableStringBuilder()
                .append("starting from")
                .append(" ")
                .append(currency)
                .append(" ")
                .bold { append(priceTxt) }
     txtviewPrice.text = s
```

I want to get the following result : "starting from $ **10.000"**

What should I change in my code to make it as the example above ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to make a specific text on TextView BOLD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14371092/how-to-make-a-specific-text-on-textview-bold)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set TextView textStyle such as bold, italic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6200533/how-to-set-textview-textstyle-such-as-bold-italic)

Answer (score 0):

Price text should be SpannableString

I would recommend you to modify your code adding this lines:

```
val priceTxt = SpannableString("10.000")
priceTxt.setSpan(StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, priceTxt.length)
```

and

```
.append(priceTxt)
```

to your builder