# obj.getString - Styling in android studio, possible?

Tags: java, android, fonts

Looking to style (bold, italic etc.) "quote" and "name", but have tried several potential solutions with no luck:

```
       private void settextView(String json) throws JSONException {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
        String[] tasks = new String[jsonArray.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            tasks[i] = obj.getString("quote") + "\n\n" + obj.getString("name");

            textView.setText(tasks[0]);
            setBtnCopyOnClick(tasks[0]); //Here

            String a = "quote";

            SpannableString spanned = new SpannableString(a);
            spanned.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 1, a.length(), Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        }
    }
```

They both generate in the same textView, so unfortunately I can only style all, or not at all.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6200533/how-to-set-textview-textstyle-such-as-bold-italic

Comment: Thanks, but there are tonnes of different variations on that post - which one do I use that is applicable to the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to style only specific parts of text you should be using spans. The Android Developers site has good documentation on this which you can read [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/spans#create-and-apply).

For your particular use case pay most attention to the [`StyleSpan`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/StyleSpan) which allows you to set `Typeface` flags.

For example:

```
String a = "underlined text";
String b = " normal text";

SpannableString spanned = new SpannableString(a + b);
spanned.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, a.length(), Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Comment: Hmm, looks like an interesting method however each time the above code is ran, the amount of characters change - therefore specifying style for number of characters would be challenging, unless I've read something wrong? It'd be great to understand if i can just get "+ obj.getString("name");" in bold.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what you mean by it being challenging? Surely you can just set the span to be the length of the string itself?

Comment: Do you mean setting a span for the length of the result, or the title (i.e. "name"). As mentioned, each time the above code is ran, the length of characters change. Sorry if I have misinterpreted what you've suggested!

Comment: Let me include an example in my answer

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work, i have updated my original question with updated code as per your instruction.

Comment: I presume you are setting the text to the new spanned string, `textView.setText(spanned);`?

Comment: Yes, however "spanned" comes up in red (thinking face)