# Display text in BOLD

Tags: android, xml, layout

How do I display my text in bold in the graphical layout of my xml? I would like my headings to be in bold, while the results are in normal format. Thank you. I hope you could help me with this matter.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/coordinates"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/instruction" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/result"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/result" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_process"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btn_text" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Original" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageSource"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/test_ideal_graph" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Result" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageAfter"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Add android:textStyle="bold" in each textview

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5169604/1434631

Answer (score 4):

In `strings.xml`

```
<string name="your_string_name"><b> I am bold text</b> And I am not bold</string>
```

Use this approach to get more flexibility in formatting text.

Also remember to use, `Html.fromHtml("your html string");` to set text in the TextView

**e.g.**

```
String s="<b> I am text in bold </b> and I am not.";
TextView t=new TextView();
t.setText(Html.fromHtml(s));
```

Answer (score 2):

For example:

```
android:textStyle="bold"
```

or when italic is wanted:

```
android:textStyle="italic"
```

For more information:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/package-summary.html

Also have look on this thread for more information:

[How do you change text to bold in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792260/how-do-you-change-text-to-bold-in-android)

Comment: What if not all content of the textView should be in bold?

Comment: use <b> and </b> and put the text that needs to be bold between the tags

Answer (score 2):

If you want all the text in the `TextView` to be bold use,

`android:textStyle="bold"`

If you only want part of it to be bold, you could generate a `Spannable` from Html using `Html.fromHtml()` like this :

`String text = "This is some <b>sample</b> text";
 yourTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));`

Here "sample" would be in bold.