# Make Text Bold / Change Text Color stored in SQLite Database, Android Studio

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am working on an offline dictionary app in android studio using SQLite database.

**I want to make some text bold or color changed which I use in SQLite database.**

How can I make text bold or can change the color of text stored in database.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you change text to bold in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792260/how-do-you-change-text-to-bold-in-android)

Comment: No, I want to make text bold in sqlite database.

Comment: Database won't show up styled text. But you can mark some text to be styled **in your app**.

Comment: How, Can you please explain. I am new to android.

Comment: Simply insert the markup where you want it to appear, surrounding the text you will store in the db. Then (in your app) you can use `HTML.fromHTML()` (very limited HTML tag support) to render it in a TextView. Or you can use a much heavier WebView.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the heading and paragraph/description in 2 different columns, then you can create 2 different `TextViews` one for the headings and set it like:

```
TextView heading = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewHeading);
heading.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
heading.setText (heading);
```

And the description/paragraph `TextView` you can set like this:

```
TextView paragraph = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewParagraph);
paragraph.setText(SQLiteHelper.Paragraph);
```

Comment: I not want to change the weight of entire words, I just want to bold headings and remaining text should remain as such

Comment: Is it certain/specific words that you want to make bold?

Comment: Yes! Headings only.

Comment: Ok then why do you want to use the database to do it? It doesn't make sense AT ALL to store text declaration in SQLite.

Comment: Then what I can do? I store text in database and did not know how to make some text bold. Thanks

Comment: Please see my new answer

Comment: Is there any way, i can chat with you and explain what I want. If you have time. Thanks for your help

Comment: Thank you but any fast way like messenger, telegram

Comment: or just I can mail you? Thanks

Comment: Yes I prefer mail

Answer (score 0):

You are welcome to store text in a database, using a data format that has a representation for bold. For example, HTML is text with "tags" for formatting, such as `<b>` for bold. Markdown — the "wikitext" language used for Stack Overflow questions and answers — uses double-asterisks for denoting boldface (e.g., `**this would be in bold**`). You are welcome to store HTML or Markdown in a database.

Comment: @M.BAndroid: That depends entirely on what you do with the text after you retrieve it from the database. For example, if you save HTML in the database, and you load that HTML into a `WebView`, anything that you marked with `<b>` tags will be show in boldface.

Comment: I tried this but it shows tags as such. (Sorry I am new to android).

Comment: @M.BAndroid: Then consider asking a separate Stack Overflow question, where you provide a [mcve] demonstrating how you are loading HTML into the `WebView`, along with a link to a screenshot showing what you are getting as a result.

Comment: Is there any other way, except sqlite database, where I can store my text easily in html format.

Comment: @M.BAndroid: You can save HTML in plain files.

Comment: I did not know how?

Comment: @M.BAndroid: File I/O in Java and Android is covered in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html) and any decent book or course on Android app development.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in sqlite but you don't need to, if you just want to change the weight on the front end of the app, but I'd have to see the code (codepen) or a screenshot at least.

Comment: Thank you, but I not want to change the weight of entire words, I just want to bold headings and remaining text should remain as such.