# In android How to applying font for whole application?

Tags: android

I want to apply some font say Times New Roman to only my application.
**Not to the whole system and not to specific view.** As far I know

to apply font to specific view we store font file in asset folder and get into the application as follow.

```
1]  Typeface  mFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),
                                     "fonts/samplefont.ttf");
    textView.setTypeface(mFace);


2] To apply font to whole application I can replace the DroidSans.ttf file with my font file.
```

I can use first way to apply font to my application but It won't be a good solution because I need to modify everywhere and  I don't want to do that if there is any better way is available.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4395309/android-want-to-set-custom-fonts-for-whole-application-not-runtime

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check this to [define fonts styles](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#DefiningStyles). In addition, you can refer to this style from your manifest file at the app level

```
<application
    android:theme="@style/Theme1">
```

Comment: I want to use font other that "monospace, Sans, Serif etc." For that I need to include fontname.ttf file into asset folder and need to refer it. How should refer file which is in asset folder.

Comment: Have a look at [Custom fonts and XML layouts (Android)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376250/custom-fonts-and-xml-layouts-android)

Comment: Neither of those examples are clear. I'm also looking to use an application wide font from a ttf format

Comment: Why is this as accepted answer? Does not help at all

Comment: This does not answer the question or even provide a hint to solve the question asked.

Answer (score 2):

I made a custom textview widget and in the constructors made a call to this code:

```
public static void SetCustomFont (TextView t, String fontName, Context c) {
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(c.getAssets(),
                fontName);
        t.setTypeface(tf);
}
```

I'm using the same font over the whole application so I put the fontName in the constuctor and then did a global Find/Replace for TextView

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376250/custom-fonts-and-xml-layouts-android/7197867#7197867 for a full coded example of this.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. You need to inherit all the textviews/buttons/... within the app - including libraries :(

Answer (score 0):

Android does not provide much in the way of support for applying fonts across the whole app (see this issue). You have 4 options to set the font for the entire app:

- Option1: Apply reflection to change the system font
- Option2: Create and subclass custom View classes for each View that needs a custom font
- Option3: Implement a View Crawler which traverses the view hierarchy for the current screen
- Option4: Use a 3rd party library.

Details of these options can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36206275/923920).