# how to set font to textview in android?

Tags: android, textview

I am doing like this but it get force close. I want to change `textview font`.

```
TextView mWeddingDataandTime=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.wedding_weddingtime_txt);
Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/CURLZ_.otf"); 
mWeddingDataandTime.setTypeface(face);
```

I am using `.otf` file. It is in assets folder. Any idea?

Comment: hi sai,first think as i known android support only ttf fonts

Comment: @imrankhan I dont think so because I have used otf files in my projects.

Comment: What does the logcat tell you? Might be a bad font.

Comment: @sai: see this post maybe helpful:[custom fonts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4395309/android-want-to-set-custom-fonts-for-whole-application-not-runtime)

Comment: hi imrankhan thank u it working....

Comment: @sai: hi sai ,can you edit your post with solution how you can do it bez it's important or  post your own solution for this post

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4395309/android-want-to-set-custom-fonts-for-whole-application-not-runtime

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.custom_font);
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Chantelli_Antiqua.ttf");
    txt.setTypeface(font);
```

Note that file extension is "ttf" search in google for any font for download in this extension

for example:
    http://www.creamundo.com/

Answer (score 0):

In code you are using `fonts/CURLZ_.otf` as path but you say that font file is directly inside assets so your code should be

```
Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"CURLZ_.otf");
```

if there is no fonts folder inside assets folder.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test it but I think it may help you:

```
  TextView mWeddingDataandTime=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.wedding_weddingtime_txt);
  Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/CURLZ_"); 
  mWeddingDataandTime.setTypeface(face);
```

Answer (score 0):

Better to make use of the styles and themes and inbuilt fonts for performance related and size of the app related issues [Styles & Themes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html)

Answer (score 0):

If your font is only in asset folder not in asser/fonts forlder than use this

```
 Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"CURLZ_.otf");
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is code which I used in my project & it's working... You might need to do some changes

```
  Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(),"segoeuil.ttf");
  TextView loantext = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.loantext);
  length1.setTypeface(myTypeface);
```

1) Put font in assets folder instead of fonts folders
2) instead of getAssests() in you code use "this.getAssets()" or "youractivity.this.getAssets()

Thank You