# recursive font change with textStyle testing for a whole activity

Tags: android, fonts

I'm trying to create a fonction to change the fonts of my app.

the aim is to create a function that I call at the end of the `onCreate()` or the `getView()` in my adapters.

but my Style test is causing a crash, I'm not sure I understand well.
If someone have an idea, it would be welcomed.

EDIT: the code bellow is correct !

```
 public static boolean recursiveFontSetting(View v){

     if( v instanceof ViewGroup){
         for(int i = 0;i<((ViewGroup) v).getChildCount();i++){
             recursiveFontSetting(((ViewGroup) v).getChildAt(i)); 
         }
         return true;
     } else if (v instanceof TextView){
        TextView e = (TextView) v;
        if(e.getTypeface()!=null && e.getTypeface().getStyle()==Typeface.BOLD){
            e.setTypeface(Constants.fontBold, Typeface.NORMAL);
        }else{

        e.setTypeface(Constants.fontReg);
        }
         return true;
     } 
     else if( v instanceof Button){
         Button e = (Button) v;
         if(e.getTypeface()!=null && e.getTypeface().getStyle()==Typeface.BOLD){
                e.setTypeface(Constants.fontBold, Typeface.NORMAL);
            }else{

            e.setTypeface(Constants.fontReg);
            }
         return true;
     }
     return false;
 }
```

Thanks !

Comment: have you seen this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4395309/android-want-to-set-custom-fonts-for-whole-application-not-runtime

Comment: absolutly, but no style testing. anyway, i've found what was missing, i'll correct my code

Comment: then please post the solution and mark it as an answer. this will help others in future also

Comment: the solution has been posted 25min ago, i can't mark it as answerd before 2 days after having created the thread. but I'll do it, i promis :)

Comment: @RenaudFavier, have you promised anything? :)