# Multiple language and font support in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fonts

I am aware of Creating a new values directory for the language with the suffix of the language code. For German: *values-de* or French: *values-fr* then copy our *string.xml* into that and translate each entry. And this works based on the Phone Localization settings

I know that , we can bypass the phone setting and and make the user select his required language inside the app using below code.

```
Locale appLoc = new Locale("en");
Locale.setDefault(appLoc);
Configuration appConfig = new Configuration();
appConfig.locale = appLoc;
getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(appConfig, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

I have give a language selection option inside my app, and make the user select the 
language he wants for the app.. dynamically switch between the string.xml (for different 
languages).

My question is ... is language option provide inside app should be support by phone 
compulsory? Because, consider that my phone don't have support for Kannada regional 
language and if user selects Kannada as language option in my app. The values are displayed 
as [][][][] (boxes). How set font support also for entire application?

I don't want use typeface for on each and every view in android as below

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/comicsans.ttf");

for(int i = 0; i <root.getChildCount(); i++) {
    View v = root.getChildAt(i);
    if(v instanceof TextView ) {
        ((TextView)v).setTypeface(tf);
    } else if(v instanceof Button) {
        ((Button)v).setTypeface(tf);
    } else if(v instanceof EditText) {
        ((EditText)v).setTypeface(tf);
    } else if(v instanceof ViewGroup) {
        changeFonts((ViewGroup)v);
    }
}
```

Can we use some local setting to configure the font for entire application?

Comment: Do you want to change local setting on device for change font style?

Comment: check this may be helpful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4395309/android-want-to-set-custom-fonts-for-whole-application-not-runtime

Comment: @Manjunathab Why did you over and over again undo the changes and breaks the formatting?

Comment: @AlexK just i was trying to format it properly

Comment: @Manjunathab Did you check the result of your editing?

Comment: @Lokesh i want support entire application with custom font. without using phone settings

Comment: @AlexK  hmmmmm i was not aware of that ....

Comment: For entire application, I think we have the chance with .ttf file. What's the problem wtih .ttf using typeface??

Comment: @Lokesh if i have some 20 textviews in each activity(i have 9 activity screens) in application .. then i need set the typeface for each textview in each activity which is very tedious... thats y looking for other alternative solution which can set for entire application.

Comment: Yes, I understood.. But, its not an issue.. you just add like a property. For example: textcolor, text size , same as text font.Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "MARKER.TTF");Text1.setTypeface(font);Text2.setTypeface(font);

Comment: @Lokesh then if i have 20 textViews then i need to have Text1.setTypeface(font) repeated for 20 textViews in each activity. can't we have some global declaration which can used for through out entire apps.   

thanks

Comment: @Satya The link is very usefull... if i have to support for some 20 different languages then things will become very tedious. Any alternative way to achieve.

thanks