# Android: To add font.. For ex. Roboto consistently throughout the application

Tags: android, typeface

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android: Want to set custom fonts for whole application not runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4395309/android-want-to-set-custom-fonts-for-whole-application-not-runtime)

I can add the fonts to my application through a simple code:

```
TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myText);
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
        "Americana Dreams Upright Bold.ttf");
txt.setTypeface(font);
```

But if i want to add this font throughout the application i have to add it for each text i have to use.
Is there a simpler way to use the font consistently throughout the application.

Can my XML show the font type(Typeface) that I specify manually?
Default Typeface are: Normal, Sans, Serif, Monospace.
Please let me know if there is a way to add font.

Comment: Duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4395309/645270)?