# How to use Roboto font in android Project

Tags: android, fonts

I have developed one android project. In this project the text font defaults to android:sans.

Now I want to replace the default text font to roboto font for my entire project.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You can download the Roboto font from here: 
https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto. [Updated 2020-01-28]

You can do it the conventional way by using `TypeFace`, like this:

```
Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), fontName);
textView.setTypeface(typeface);
```

Note: The above will have to be done in every `Activity`.

Alternatively, if, for example, you want to apply the Roboto font to all the `TextView`s in your application, then you will need to create your own widget that extends `TextView`.

There is a simple way of doing this. Follow the steps from this answer on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9199258/450534 (full props to [**leocadiotine**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1054366/leocadiotine) for the solution. I have used it before and it works like a charm)

EDIT: Think of `your_namespace` as a marker for you to give it a name of your choice. For example, when integrating Admob in XML, I use `xmlns:ads`. You can use, for example: `xmlns:font` or something descriptive.

As for what the *custom.ttf* stands for, it is basically the font file with its extension that you need to copy in your `Assets` folder. For example, if you are using **ROBOTO-REGULAR.TTF**, then replace the *custom.ttf* with *ROBOTO-REGULAR.TTF*. Using this example, the entire code should look this this:

```
<your.package.widget.TypefacedTextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:font="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/your.package"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Custom fonts in XML are easy"
    android:textColor="#FFF"
    android:textSize="14dip"
    font:typeface="ROBOTO-REGULAR.TTF" />
```

Comment: Font can be found in SDK in `platforms/android-X/data/fonts/` since X 11 (if I remember correctly when it was introduced).

Comment: @WebnetMobile.com: I know. But I think there are a few missing in the SDK. The one off the Android webpage has 16.

Comment: Sidddharth Lele: u mentioned in xml file that your_namespace, what it is? , and my assest folder not having custom.tff , then what to do, and what is the use of custom.ttf ??

Comment: @SiddharthLele how can I use bold style under this configuration with Trykker font?. I'm trying android:textStyle="bold" but does not take effect

Comment: @Ricardo: When you use a Font other than he default Android Fonts, the attribute `android:textStyle="...."` is ignored. To make it bold, you will need to use the bold version .ttf / .otf font file. The _Trykker_ font, however, has just the regular version and no other variants.

Comment: is it just me or is there no download link on the page you linked to download roboto font?

Comment: @adamjohns: It's not just you. They changed the link when they rolled out Material Design pages. And I didn't realize the link doesn't work until you commented. Thank you. Link has been updated.

Comment: @IceMAN To do this for each and every widget in an application is an insane amount of work, And even worse, totally inflexible.

Comment: @f470071: I agree. Entirely. But that being said, there simply was no easier way of doing that when this answer was posted. Even libraries like [Calligraphy](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy), which is a better alternative to this answer, still needs every widget to define a custom font. Or use just one custom throughout the application. At this point, my best guess is, unless Google provides an _out-of-the-box_ option, this is as best as it goes.

Comment: if you are setting midSdk to 16, you can set the roboto font natively, no need to download any font. Here is the example:
From android 4.1 / 4.2, the following Roboto font families are available:

android:fontFamily="sans-serif"           // roboto regular  
android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"     // roboto light  
android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed" // roboto condensed  
android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"      // roboto thin (android 4.2)  
android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"

Answer (score 25):

1. [Download](https://material.io/design/typography/the-type-system.html#type-scale) and unzip the `Roboto` font zip file
2. Create a `assets` folder in your project if you don't have one already. Am assuming you are using Android Studio, this is how to do it.
   [image]
3. Create a new directory in the assets folder, name it `font`.
4. Open your unzipped file and copy the font style of your choice. Your font folder shouls look like this:

[image]

You can now use this font anywhere in your app like this:

```
   Typeface roboto = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), 
  "font/Roboto-Bold.ttf"); //use this.getAssets if you are calling from an Activity
   txtView.setTypeface(roboto);
```

Comment: So this should be done for each and every widget?? Horrible.

Comment: Page not found - 404

Comment: @EvgenyFedin recheck

Answer (score 6):

```
txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtView);

Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(
                          this.getAssets(),
                          "font/Robot.otf");

txtView.setTypeface(myTypeface);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do this easily by using the [Typerlib](https://github.com/elmargomez/typer).

> This library wraps the complexity of adding a font resource in your
>   project and recycle those recently created font inorder to maximize
>   your app's perfromance.

Add this to your `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.elmargomez.typer:typerlib:1.0.0'
}
```

Then you can use the font by

```
TextView txtView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourTxtView1);
TextView txtView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourTxtView2);
TextView txtView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourTxtView3);
TextView txtView4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourTxtView4);

txtView1.setTypeface(Typer.set(yourContext).getFont(Font.ROBOTO_REGULAR));
txtView2.setTypeface(Typer.set(yourContext).getFont(Font.ROBOTO_CONDENSED_ITALIC));
txtView3.setTypeface(Typer.set(yourContext).getFont(Font.ROBOTO_THIN));
txtView4.setTypeface(Typer.set(yourContext).getFont(Font.ROBOTO_BOLD));
```

It includes all the current fonts in Roboto
,Like:

```
    Font.ROBOTO_MEDIUM
    Font.ROBOTO_REGULAR
    etc.
```

To view all available fonts use Android Studio Auto complete after the class **Font** by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd>.

Answer (score 3):

One more remark for the usage of `Typeface.createFromAsset()` function. When I had many calls on it it significantly impacted the inflate time. To overcome this issue we created a singleton instance of the `Typeface` like this

```
public static Typeface getTypeFace() {
        if (fromAsset == null) {
            fromAsset = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf");
        }
        return fromAsset;
    }
```