# Helvetica Alternative in Android

Tags: android, fonts

I'm looking for a Helvetica font alternative for Android. It seems that this font is not included in Android, but is in iOS. What would be a good alternative?

--EDIT--

In addition to the answer below, a colleague found that Raleway-Thin.ttf is close to Helvetica.

Comment: Do they have Arial?  As much as I hate Arial, it's the standard Helvetica replacement.

Comment: @JoeZ it looks like Android doesn't support Arial either, unless a .ttf file is added to the project: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16183660/3006350

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Android uses the [Roboto](http://developer.android.com/design/style/typography.html) font, which is a really nice looking font, with a few different weights (regular, light, thin, condensed) that look great on high density screens.

If you want to use a custom font (like helvetica), you will need to implement custom textview/edittext widgets that use that font.

Comment: Your second link is broken.

Comment: I believe this has changed since this answer has been written. See the `create*` functions in the [Typeface](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Typeface.html) class.