# Helvetica Neue font in iOS App

Tags: ios, ios7, fonts, licensing

I just want to know if it´s legal to use the Font "HelveticaNeue" in my iOS 7 App which i want to put in the AppStore? The font is included in MacOS Mavericks and i am able to choose it in Xcode or call it in code like this:

I already took a look here at other questions, but didn´t find any one related to mine...

```
[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-UltraLight" size:size]
```

So do i have to buy i license or can i just use it?! Has anyone experience with this?

Comment: it is the default one , u can use normally , i used my last 5 projects

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use it. Its free to use and you don't need any license as its system provided.
Hope this helps.

Comment: And able to use in my android App, too?!

Comment: Yes, If it's available. From this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20598541/helvetica-alternative-in-android it seems like its not. If so, you may use an alternative that closely matches. Check this link for more info http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/11396/i-want-to-use-helvetica-neue-in-my-android-application-where-do-i-buy-the-appro Note that your question was tagged for iOS so Android related queries are best avoided :)

Comment: @chrizstone You cannot bundle the Helvetica Neue font freely in your Android app for free. However, there are a number of Google font alternatives to it that can be bundled in your Android app. These are: Source Sans Pro, Lato, PT Sans, Open Sans

Comment: @akdsouza can I use this font without any legal issues in iOS14, for example?

Comment: @eltray yes you can as it is a system font on iOS

Answer (score 0):

You can use it.

Helvetica Neue is the default font on iOS 7 and is free to use for app developers. You can freely use any of the fonts in Xcode for your apps