# android app design using only one font

Tags: android

i've designed an app for either phone and tablet. When I launch the app on an samsung device it gets that ugly font from samsung. Is it possible to restrict the application to only use 1 font on every device. The roboto font would be nice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated here: [How to use Roboto font in android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13539688/how-to-use-roboto-font-in-android-project)

I believe you have to download the Roboto font, and from there you can use the TypeFace class to set the font for all your Activities.  As long as you bundle the font with your project, the font should remain constant throughout all devices.