# String types not allowed (at 'android:typeface' with value 'Calibri.ttf')

Tags: android, typeface

How I can set a custom font as an application font? Here is my setup:

1. The custom font is located in `/assets/fonts/Calibri.TTF`
2. In my manifest, I set the application theme like so: `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"`
3. Here is my `style.xml`:

`<resources>
    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
        <item name="android:typeface">Calibri.ttf</item>
    </style>
</resources>`

Now I cannot run this app. When I try to compile it, I a get an error like this:

```
error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'android:typeface' with value 'Calibri.ttf')
```

Comment: You cannot apply in style...try this way in java code. http://stackoverflow.com/a/13539825/1608643

Comment: @KetanAhir  SO How can I set a font as application font.

Comment: create custom TextView and use it in your app. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4395309/android-want-to-set-custom-fonts-for-whole-application-not-runtime/9199258#9199258

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rename your customs fonts from Calibri.ttf to calibri.ttf

and secondly you can't directly give fonts in resource file

try to refer this on github

https://gist.github.com/artem-zinnatullin/7749076

Answer (score 2):

typeface value should be like these values. "normal,sans,serif,monospace"

Comment: Thanks so how i can set it,
Now I have changed the code to 
<item name="android:fontFamily">Calibri.ttf</item> 
Now I can run the project but the font is not applying for the application.

Comment: No you can't. You cannot add custom fonts via xml

Answer (score 0):

Yes with reflection. This works have a look on following stackoverflow question [Is it possible to set a custom font for entire of application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711858/is-it-possible-to-set-font-for-entire-application)