# How to apply custom font for the whole app?

Tags: android, custom-controls

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android: Want to set custom fonts for whole application not runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4395309/android-want-to-set-custom-fonts-for-whole-application-not-runtime)

I know there is way of doing it in the following way. But I want to apply the font to the entire application. Is that possible?

```
TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.customfont);
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Molot.otf");
txt.setTypeface(font);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not possible to give one for the entire application however, if you look at the accepted response on:

[Android: Want to set custom fonts for whole application not runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4395309/android-want-to-set-custom-fonts-for-whole-application-not-runtime)

they have a solution that makes it easier to set it to any view easier :) Another method is creating a custom widget to replace TextView, but if you require the font on other widgets too, it gets quite messy!