# How use Android supplied (custom) fonts?

Tags: android, fonts, textview, android-assets, android-sdk-2.3

According to the [Android Typography](https://developer.android.com/design/style/typography.html) page Roboto font was introduced in Ice Cream Sandwich. I can download the `.ttf` files there or I can find it (and many others) in the `<android-sdk>/platforms/android-x/data/fonts` directory (where x is ICS version and higher).

If I want to actually use this font in my app do I still need to copy this to my `assets/fonts` directory and setup the font like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4395309/android-want-to-set-custom-fonts-for-whole-application-not-runtime/9199258#9199258) or is there some other way of accessing it in my layout XML files?

**EDIT:**

To clarify the question I really mean *any* of the Android supplied fonts. So if you look in Android Lollipop's font folder (`android-sdk/platforms/android-21/data`) there are lots of new fonts.

Assume on a single layout I want to use `Roboto-Italic` in one `TextView` and (say) `NotoSerif-Bold` in another. Can I specify that in my XML layout file using `android:typeface="..."` or do I need to manually copy the required `.ttf` files to my font folder and subclass the `TextView` widget?

Comment: you can check my answer, with that code you can do that, don't forget check as correct.

Comment: thanks Adrian... I marked Kevin's answer as correct as he answered before you :(.. you all basically answered my question and I had to choose one... I upvoted everyone though! Really appreciate your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi you would need to set the typeface on a TextView like below:

```
Typeface yourTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/" + fontName + ".ttf");
yourTextView.setTypeface(yourTypeface);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. So am I right in thinking that I still have to copy the appropriate `.tff` file to my project's `assets/fonts` directory?

Comment: yes all your .ttf files you require will go in there :)

Comment: ok thanks for that. Its strange that if I am developing for lollipop and above I can't actually specify these fonts (which I know are installed on the phone somewhere!). Instead I have to copy files around and manually create `Typeface` types.

Comment: Well heres a link to download official Roboto http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/typography.html

Answer (score 2):

The Roboto font is already used by default on android 4.0 and up, so you don't need to do anything.

Comment: Hi.. thanks for your help. I added more detail to my question to clarify it a bit better. Sorry for the ambiguity.

Comment: In that case, use the answer by @Adrian. You have to copy the TTF file into your project. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12128331/how-to-change-fontfamily-of-textview-in-android)

Answer (score 2):

If you want set Roboto as your font, you must verify what is your version, if you have Android < 4.0 you must do something like this

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/roboto.ttf");

TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
text.setTypeface(font);
```

But if your version is 4.0 or higher as JonasCz says, is not necessary, you can read more about this in https://developer.android.com/design/style/typography.html

Note: copy the fonts to assets/fonts. This code is useful also to put any font in your views.