# How to change font type when textview is part of a listview

Tags: android, listview, fonts, textview

I have a listview populated like this:

```
lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("product", "Bread");
map.put("quantity", "1");
map.put("unit", "pcs");
mylist.add(map);

map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("product", "Books for mom");
map.put("quantity", "14");
map.put("unit", "pcs");
mylist.add(map);

map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("product", "Mineral water");
map.put("quantity", "2");
map.put("unit", "l");
mylist.add(map);

SimpleAdapter mSchedule = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist, R.layout.grlists,
    new String[] {"product", "quantity", "unit"}, new int[] {R.id.CPRODUCT, R.id.CQUANTITY, R.id.CUNIT});
lv1.setAdapter(mSchedule);
```

This is the layout of the listview (grlists.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:paddingTop="4dip"
     android:paddingBottom="6dip"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal">
    <CheckBox android:id="@+id/checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
     <TextView android:id="@+id/CPRODUCT"
         android:layout_width="200dip"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:textColor="#000000"
         android:paddingLeft="5dip"
         android:background="#EBDDE2"/>

     <TextView android:id="@+id/CQUANTITY"
         android:layout_width="30dip"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"
          android:textColor="#000000"
          android:background="#B4CFEC"/>

     <TextView android:id="@+id/CUNIT"
         android:layout_width="30dip"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:layout_weight="1"
          android:textColor="#000000"
          android:background="#A5A1A0"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

This gives me nullpointerexception because it looks for the CPRODUCT textview in the main layout.

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/PopStarAutograph.ttf");
TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CPRODUCT);
tv1.setTypeface(tf);
```

How can i change the font type of the textviews programmatically?

Comment: Do you want your list rows to have this font from the start or change it later after you create the list?

Comment: Here is your answer, please use search.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576441/custom-font-in-android-listview

Comment: slukian: I want them to have a default custom font type, but I also want to add the user the option to change it

Comment: Thanks dmytrodanylyk! Please add this as an answer so I could accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Dmytro Danylyk did not add his solution as an answer I add it to close this question. However, in the past months I have mastered this area, so I add a bit different answer as he posted.

First of all, we need arrays to show in a listview. This listview is built upon a custom adapter that receives the items from the arrays. In this custom adapter  we can do whatever want with the items in each row of a listview, no matter what kind of elements we are talking about. Be it a textview, imageview, or a checkbox, etc.

Let's imagine we have 5 elements in a list row: 5 textviews. After populating the 5 arrays, we define our adapter as:

```
adapter = new ListViewCustomAdapter(Calllogs.this, arr_calllog_name, arr_calllog_phone, arr_calllog_type,arr_calllog_duration, arr_calllog_date);
```

And this is how we set our adapter to the listview:

```
lv1.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And finally, we need to create our ListViewCustomAdapter (name it as you want):

```
public class ListViewCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    public String title[];
    public String description[];
    ArrayList<String> arr_calllog_name = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> arr_calllog_phone = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> arr_calllog_type = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> arr_calllog_date = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> arr_calllog_duration = new ArrayList<String>();

    public Activity context;
    public LayoutInflater inflater;

    public ListViewCustomAdapter(Activity context,  ArrayList<String> arr_calllog_name, ArrayList<String> arr_calllog_phone, ArrayList<String> arr_calllog_type, ArrayList<String> arr_calllog_duration, ArrayList<String> arr_calllog_date) {
        super();

        this.context = context;
        this.arr_calllog_type = arr_calllog_type;
        this.arr_calllog_name = arr_calllog_name;
        this.arr_calllog_phone = arr_calllog_phone;
        this.arr_calllog_date = arr_calllog_date;
        this.arr_calllog_duration = arr_calllog_duration;


        this.inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arr_calllog_name.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder
    {
        TextView txtViewTitle;
        TextView txtViewDescription;
        TextView txtDate;
        TextView txtDuration;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView==null)
        {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.calllog_row, null);

            holder.txtViewTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.calllogquery_name);
            holder.txtViewDescription = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.calllogquery_phone);
            holder.txtDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.calllogquery_date);
            holder.txtDuration = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.calllogquery_duration);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
            holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();

        int teljes = Integer.parseInt(arr_calllog_duration.get(position));
        int h = teljes / 3600;
        int mar_h = teljes - h * 3600;
        int m = mar_h / 60;
        int s = mar_h - m * 60;
        String hh, mm, ss;
        if (h < 10)                 {                   hh = "0" + Integer.toString(h);             }
        else                {                   hh = Integer.toString(h);               }
        if (m < 10)                 {                   mm = "0" + Integer.toString(m);             }
        else                {                   mm = Integer.toString(m);               }
        if (s < 10)             {                   ss = "0" + Integer.toString(s);             }
        else                {                   ss = Integer.toString(s);               }

        String dur_edited = hh + ":" + mm + ":" + ss;


        holder.txtViewTitle.setText(arr_calllog_name.get(position));
        holder.txtViewDescription.setText(arr_calllog_phone.get(position));
        holder.txtDate.setText(arr_calllog_date.get(position));
        holder.txtDuration.setText(dur_edited);

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

As you see this adapter has 5 parameters, just like our 5 arrays. That's all.
Oh, and we also need to define our adapter as `ListViewCustomAdapter adapter;` first.

You can have this adapter class in a separate class or in your activity, outside the onCreate() method.