# Want to display data in Indian Regional language(Telugu,Hindi,Tamil and Malayalam) from RSSFeed in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, indic

I am developing an application for newspaper. I want to get the data from a RSSfeed and I want to display the data in a ListView manner with Regional Languages. How can this be done in android?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use specific font for a language. Check this for [custom font in android ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576441/custom-font-in-android-listview)

---

### Code for setting custom font to TextView:

Assuming you have the **your_font.ttf** font in **fonts** folder under **assets** folder:

```
 Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/your_font.ttf");               
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CustomFontText);
    tv.setTypeface(tf);
```