# Am developing RSS News FeedReader for Telugu News Paper?how can i Display Telugu Fonts in Android?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Want to display data in Indian Regional language(Telugu,Hindi,Tamil and Malayalam) from RSSFeed in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10687653/want-to-display-data-in-indian-regional-languagetelugu-hindi-tamil-and-malayala)

[image]

I want to Develope app for telugu news paper like this can anyone help me,I want to take the data from RSS News Feedreader...
i already tried

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/your_font.ttf");  
   TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CustomFontText);
   tv.setTypeface(tf);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please don't repeat your questions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10687653/want-to-display-data-in-indian-regional-languagetelugu-hindi-tamil-and-malayala

Comment: @KazekageGaara Am not getting the correct answer from viewers thats way i sended and am using that method but still am not getting anyway thanks Gaara