# Slow transition of Activities: multiple "initializing inflate state" in LogCat

Tags: android, android-listview, custom-component, android-logcat

In order to provide a custom typeface in my `ListActivity`, I wrote a class `CustomAdapter` extending `BaseAdapter` according to this example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576441/custom-font-in-android-listview).

However, as described there, I wrote the `getView()` method like following:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    String gameName = gameNames[position]; // gameName ist the String[] of the Custom Adapter

    TextView tv = new TextView(context);
    tv.setText(gameName);
    tv.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/gulim.ttf"));

    return tv;
}
```

This works as intended. The only disturbing thing is that it takes about three or four seconds until the list shows up (and this is a very long time in this context). However, in the `ListActivity` I set the `onItemClickListener`s like this:

```
private void setOnItemClickListener(){
    getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id){
            onClickEntryButton(((TextView) view).getText().toString());
        }
    });
}

private void onClickEntryButton(String gameName){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, GameActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("gameName", gameName);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

Now when clicking on a `ListItem`, it takes even more time until the `GameActivity` opens. This `Activity` is just a couple of `TextView`s filled with information taken from a SQLite database. Also here, I set a custom typeface to every `TextView`. It happens even that the screen gets black for 2-3 seconds (appearing the app crashed), then the new `Activity` shows up. This doesn't happen accessing that `Activity` from other places in the application.

In both cases - accessing the `ListActivity` and accessing the `GameActivity` from the `ListActivity` - a couple of

> "szipinf - Initializing inflate state"

messages appear in the LogCat. What does they mean in this context? Would it be a better usage to set the `onItemClickListener`s into the `getView()` method of my `CustomAdapter`? Something seems to really inhibit the transitions, but I can't figure out what, since there is nothing big to be calculated or processed (in fact, in the SQLite database are exactly two entries with each 5 fields)?

**EDIT**
If required or desired, of course I can provide more code.

Answer (score 4):

I had exactly same issue and your question gave me answer!

I still do not know exact root cause but this the isuue is because of reading custom font from assets multiple times in my case.
If I have 10 widgets in my screen and each of them is using custom font Android loads it from assets everytime. which was not just causing my activity transions to become slow it was also resulting in crash after playing with it multiple tmes.

So I created a cache for my typeface to avoid fetching typeface everytime from assets.

I added this code inside my utility class:

```
private static final Hashtable<String, Typeface> cache = new Hashtable<String, Typeface>();

public static final String ASSET_PATH="assetPath";

public static Typeface getFont(Context c, String assetPath) {
    synchronized (cache) {
        if (!cache.containsKey(assetPath)) {
            try {
                Typeface t =(Typeface.createFromAsset(c.getAssets(),
                        "fonts/arial.ttf"));
                cache.put(assetPath, t);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }
        }
        return cache.get(assetPath);
    }
}
```

I created my custom class to to setTypeface

```
public class MyButton extends Button {

public MyButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public MyButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public MyButton(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
public void setTypeface(Typeface tf) {

    super.setTypeface(Util.getFont(getContext(), Util.ASSET_PATH));
}

}
```

variable assetPath can be used to provide diffrent fonts at runtime

**EDIT**: [Here](https://github.com/NayaneshGupte/RobotoTypefaceManager) is custom typefaceManager I have created as a library to make it more generic.