# How to set the custom font to dynamically created listView?

Tags: android, listview, fonts, android-fonts

I am newbie to android. I need to set the custom font to listview?

How to set the font?
My code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

String[] presidents = { "Dwight D. Eisenhower", "John F. Kennedy",
        "Lyndon B. Johnson", "Richard Nixon", "Gerald Ford",
        "Jimmy Carter", "Ronald Reagan", "George H. W. Bush",
        "Bill Clinton", "George W. Bush", "Barack Obama"

};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // ---no need to call this---
    // setContentView(R.layout.main);

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, presidents));       
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to create a custom adapter, and set the font of the items in the adapter. See this for an example: [custom font in android ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576441/custom-font-in-android-listview)