# Display Hindi/Tamil/Telugu text in android application

Tags: android, database, android-layout, android-listview, fonts

I have a rooted phone and was trying to play around with my phone. It has android 2.2 installed. What I want to do is to display Hndi/Tamil/Telugu text inside the application that I was trying to develop. Obviously android 2.2 does not support these fonts.

As the phone is rooted doing this was easy for one language. I just followed the tips given in this link [Enable Hindi Fonts on Rooted Device](http://chetangole.com/blog/2011/08/enabling-installing-hindi-marathi-unicode-fonts-on-android-mobile/) and was able to get Hindi fonts throughout the system. Similar approach helped me setup Tamil fonts.

But I am not able to make both Hindi and Tamil work together. The possible solutions I can think off are :

i) Create a common ttf file which shall contain both Hindi and Tamil fonts. But I have no idea whether this is possible or not.

ii) Keep a .ttf file for each language in the assets/fonts/ folder but again this is showing just square boxes on the device.

I tried this link [Display Different Languages In Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576441/custom-font-in-android-listview/)too but again this seems to work for only supported fonts.

Any guidance would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Solved. My i) approach was correct. Use this DroidSansFallBack.ttf file and save it in your /system/fonts/ folder. Reboot the device and you have support for these languages : Hindi(Devanagari), Kannada, Bengali, Oriya, Malayalam, Telugu, Tamil, Punjabi.[http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=798380]

Answer (score 0):

Try this [sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22495332/how-to-display-south-indian-languages-in-android/22497074#22497074) application.I shared here the whole application code for how to display one text in multiple languages especially Kannada and Telugu.