# How to set custom (arial )type face via xml not via a java code

Tags: android, textview

I already aware of this:-
Typeface typefaceArial= Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "arial.ttf");

but when I create the following class it works but it gives **low memory warning** issue.

public class MidColorTextView extends TextView
{

```
private CharSequence text;
private String token;
private static Context context;
private String colorSpan;
private int colorCode;
private static Typeface typefaceArial;

public MidColorTextView( Context context , AttributeSet attrs )
{
    super(context, attrs);
    this.context=null;
    this.context = context;


    for(int i = 0; i < attrs.getAttributeCount(); i ++ )
    {
        // Log.i(TAG, attrs.getAttributeName(i));
        /*
         * Read value of custom attributes
         */

        this.text = attrs.getAttributeValue("http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.lht", "text");

        this.token = attrs.getAttributeValue("http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.lht", "token");
        this.colorSpan = attrs.getAttributeValue("http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.lht", "colorSpan");
        // Log.i("TAG", "token " + token);
        // Log.i("TAG", "text " + text);
        // Log.i("TAG", "colorSpan " + colorSpan);

    }
    init();
}

private void init ()
{
    if(text.charAt(0) == '@')
    {
        String tempText = (String) text.subSequence(1, text.length());
        this.text = Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(Integer.parseInt(tempText)));

    }
    if(token.charAt(0) == '@')
    {
        String tempText = (String) token.subSequence(1, token.length());
        this.token = getResources().getString(Integer.parseInt(tempText));
    }
    if(colorSpan.charAt(0) == '@')
    {
        String tempText = (String) colorSpan.subSequence(1, colorSpan.length());
        this.colorSpan = getResources().getString(Integer.parseInt(tempText));
    }

    setColorCode(Color.parseColor(colorSpan));

    CharSequence textWitoutToken = null;
    String tempString = text.toString();

    // ---------checking whether text containg token or not.
    if(tempString.contains(token))
    {
        textWitoutToken = setSpanBetweenTokens(text, token, new ForegroundColorSpan(colorCode));
    }
    else
    {
        textWitoutToken = text;
    }
    textContent = null;
    setText(textWitoutToken);
    setTypefaceArial ();
    setTypeface(getTypefaceArial ());

}



public int getColorCode ()
{
    return colorCode;
}

public void setColorCode ( int colorCode )
{
    this.colorCode = colorCode;
}

private CharSequence textContent;


public static Typeface getTypefaceArial ()
{
    return typefaceArial;
}
public static void setTypefaceArial ()
{
    MidColorTextView.typefaceArial= Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "arial.ttf");
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue via using singleton class.
I am giving the complete code so that it can help others.

**1.** Define this in XML:

```
    xmlns:lht="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.lht"     android:id="@+id/basicLayout"

    <com.xyz.util.MidColorTextView
            xyz:token="#" 
            xyz:colorSpan="@color/BrightRed"
            xyz:text="@string/AppraisingStaffBottomText_imanage"
            style="@style/contentDescriptionText" />
```

**2.** Create class `MidColorTextView`

```
    package com.xyz.util;

    public class MidColorTextView extends TextView {

    private CharSequence text;
    private String token;
    private  Context context;
    private String colorSpan;
    private int colorCode;


    public MidColorTextView( Context context , AttributeSet attrs ) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.context = context;


        for(int i = 0; i < attrs.getAttributeCount(); i ++ ) {
            // Log.i(TAG, attrs.getAttributeName(i));
            /*
             * Read value of custom attributes
             */

            this.text = attrs.getAttributeValue("http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.xyz", "text");

            this.token = attrs.getAttributeValue("http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.xyz", "token");
            this.colorSpan = attrs.getAttributeValue("http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.xyz", "colorSpan");
            // Log.i("TAG", "token " + token);
            // Log.i("TAG", "text " + text);
            // Log.i("TAG", "colorSpan " + colorSpan);

        }
        init();
    }

    private void init () {

        if(text.charAt(0) == '@') {
            String tempText = (String) text.subSequence(1, text.length());
            this.text = Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(Integer.parseInt(tempText)));

        }
        if(token.charAt(0) == '@') {
            String tempText = (String) token.subSequence(1, token.length());
            this.token = getResources().getString(Integer.parseInt(tempText));
        }
        if(colorSpan.charAt(0) == '@')
        {
            String tempText = (String) colorSpan.subSequence(1, colorSpan.length());
            this.colorSpan = getResources().getString(Integer.parseInt(tempText));
        }

        setColorCode(Color.parseColor(colorSpan));

        CharSequence textWitoutToken = null;
        String tempString = text.toString();

        // ---------checking whether text containg token or not.
        if(tempString.contains(token))
        {
            textWitoutToken = setSpanBetweenTokens(text, token, new ForegroundColorSpan(colorCode));
        }
        else
        {
            textWitoutToken = text;
        }
        textContent = null;
        setText(textWitoutToken);
        setTypeface(FontManager.getInstance(context).getTypefaceArial ());

    }

    public void setText ( CharSequence text , String token , int color )
    {
        setText(setSpanBetweenTokens(text, token, new ForegroundColorSpan(color)));

        setTypeface(FontManager.getInstance(context).getTypefaceArial ());

    }

    public int getColorCode ()
    {
        return colorCode;
    }

    public void setColorCode ( int colorCode )
    {
        this.colorCode = colorCode;
    }

    private CharSequence textContent;

    public CharSequence setSpanBetweenTokens ( CharSequence text , String token , CharacterStyle... cs )
    {
        // Start and end refer to the points where the span will apply
        int tokenLen = token.length();
        int start = text.toString().indexOf(token) + tokenLen;
        int end = text.toString().indexOf(token, start);
        if(start > - 1 && end > - 1)
        {
            // Copy the spannable string to a mutable spannable string
            SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder(text);
            for(CharacterStyle c : cs)
            {
                ssb.setSpan(c, start, end, 0);
            }
            // Delete the tokens before and after the span
            ssb.delete(end, end + tokenLen);
            ssb.delete(start - tokenLen, start);

            text = ssb;
            textContent = ssb;
            String tempString = textContent.toString();
            if(tempString.contains(token))
            {
                setSpanBetweenTokens(textContent, token, new ForegroundColorSpan(colorCode));
            }

        }

        return textContent;
    }

    }
```

**3.** Create class `FontManager`

```
public class FontManager {
    private Typeface typefaceArial;
    private  Context context;

    private static FontManager instance = null;

    private FontManager(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        this.typefaceArial= Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "arial.ttf");
    }

    public synchronized static FontManager getInstance(Context context) {
        if(instance == null) {
            instance = new FontManager(context);
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public Typeface getTypefaceArial () {
        return typefaceArial;
    }

}
```

This will solve all your problems.

`setSpanBetweenTokens` is used for the color text between specific tokens.

Here is a string resource to test on:

```
<string name="AppraisingStaffBottomText_imanage">The meeting&lt;br>&lt;br>PAST&lt;br>Allow the employee to give you
        their view of their positive
        progress over the past period, focus them on this with open
        questions, such as:&lt;br>&lt;i>#\"What has been your important contribution over the past
        6
        months?\"#&lt;/i>&lt;br>&lt;i>#\"What have your learned about your role?\"#&lt;/i>&lt;br>
        &lt;i>#\"What has been your important success?\"#&lt;/i>&lt;br>Don\'t rake over past mistakes,
        don\'t focus on poor performance
        - you cannot change that, reserve those discussions future
        development - see below&lt;br>&lt;br>PRESENT&lt;br>Using open questions, help staff to identify
        their true strengths,
        capabilities, attributes, skills and attitudes. Create a
        comprehensive picture of them as a strategic contributor and
        resource.&lt;br>What are your skills, and to what level?&lt;br>&lt;i>#\"What have you added as
        capabilities over the past months?\"#&lt;/i>&lt;br>&lt;i>#\"What do you find are your
        most useful personal attributes in
        your role?\"#&lt;/i>&lt;br>&lt;br>FUTURE&lt;br>The future is the period where changes in
        capability and
        performance can be made.&lt;br>This discussion is where your people can figure out -
        with your
        help - what development they need to reach your performance
        standards and their career goals. It begins with understanding
        their career goals, so ....&lt;br>&lt;i>#\"What are your goals?\"#&lt;/i>&lt;br>&lt;i>#\"What
        development will be needed?\"#&lt;/i>
        &lt;br>&lt;i>#\"You have seen over the past months that you may need more skill in these
        areas .......................... what should we do about
        that?\"#&lt;/i>&lt;br>&lt;br>Finally: Agree a specific development plan that includes
        training/experience in the areas where more skill is needed. Fix dates
        in the diary&lt;br>&lt;br>The Manager\'s role is one of Mentor and Guide; not
        Judge and
        Jury</string>
```

Comment: To save us having to study all your code, could you maybe include a few words about your approach? For example, which class is the singleton? Also, is all that HTML at the end intentional? And finally, please fix the markup in your answer—refer to http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the typeface as a [style](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html)

But a specific font, only in java code: [ApiDemo](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/Typefaces.html)

To understand what is causing the low memory error,

- make sure it is not a problem with that particular font (for example, try [this font](http://moorstation.org/typoasis/designers/klein07/text01/handmade.htm), which has been used in [this example of a class extending TextView](https://www.androidguys.com/news/fun-with-fonts/).
- reduce the non-specific code and test your class with a bare minimum code (i.e., `typefaceArial=Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "arial.ttf")` and `this.text ="Testing text";` as part of the constructor, eliminating all the `attrs.getAttributeValue()` methods and specially the `init()` method, etc.)

Once you get those two changes, you will be able to tell whether is the Typeface assignment a problem, or something else.

Comment: Thanks for your response.But I already did it through xml but I am facing issue regarding low memory warning as I mentioned earlier

Comment: Yes I ran the test case and remove the attrs and init().But it only because of the typeface.
http://groups.google.com/group/android-ndk/browse_thread/thread/4e5c85aa5a4d3ea4
Same issue in this post but not able to solve the issue.
Thanks for your precious time.

Comment: Post your simplified code instead, so people can take a look at it. Also, why do you have `this.context=null;this.context = context;` in the constructor?

Comment: I am just trying some thing I simplyfi the code in below post,thank for you consideration.

Answer (score 0):

public class MidColorTextView extends TextView {
    private String token;
    private static Context context;
    private String colorSpan;
    private int colorCode;
    private static Typeface typefaceArial;

```
public MidColorTextView( Context context , AttributeSet attrs )
{
    super(context, attrs);

    this.context = context;


    init();
}

private void init ()
{



    setTypefaceArial ();
    setTypeface(getTypefaceArial ());

}



public int getColorCode ()
{
    return colorCode;
}

public void setColorCode ( int colorCode )
{
    this.colorCode = colorCode;
}

private CharSequence textContent;


public static Typeface getTypefaceArial ()
{
    return typefaceArial;
}
public static void setTypefaceArial ()
{
    MidColorTextView.typefaceArial= Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "arial.ttf");
}
```

}