# Button with text aligned left and right

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm pretty new in android development and I need your help.
I need button with bold text aligned to the left hand side and another text with different font (smaller and different colour) aligned to the right, something like that:

```
[**Name**           john]
//Name is bold and black
// john is smaller and let's say blue
```

I did a researched online but I couldn't find anything.
I tried:

```
this.button.setText(Html.fromHtml(styledText));
```

But it looks like it doesn't work with `alignment="right"`, `text-allign:right` or even 
`float:right`.

I also find another solution to use table layout and table row but I need to have one button which will fired some action. I don't want two buttons for two parts of the text.

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: Text in button is in center by default, so if you add some spaces between, your two parts shall be apart automatically

Comment: Use linear layout with two textview and treat that linear layout as button. So you can change font color and size of both textview.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7328890/custom-button-with-two-textview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Step 1:** res/drawable/button_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_bg_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_bg_normal"></item>
</selector>
```

**Step 2:** Create one LinearLayout with two TextView.

```
           <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/myCustomButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:background="@drawable/button_selector" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:background="@drawable/ai_contact_us" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/aiResetPwdButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:textColor="@color/blue"/>

            </LinearLayout>
```

**Step 3:** In your onCreate()

```
View buttonView = findViewById(R.id.myCustomButton);
buttonView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListenet(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried your code and it layout  the views right exactly as I want but the row is not changed the background once tapped.

Comment: Have you keep **res/drawable/button_selector.xml** this file and both drawable .png or .jpg file for background change on pressed and normal state?

Comment: Yes I added it to drawable mdpi and I changed the images to colours "@android:color/dark_gray"

Comment: No, i think it won't accept color pls use drawable. try with @drawable/button_bg_normal

Comment: What I want to achieve is white(transparent)background for normal button state and fray when the button is pressed. I've created list of the buttons and first of those has rounded top rectangle the middle one are square and the last one has rounded bottom rectangle. I haven't got images for every single state of the buttons. It would be easier to use colours.

Comment: Are you using shape for background?

Comment: Yes, I have LinearLayout with shape background which contains buttons separate by views (just line).

Answer (score 0):

Don't use button, it's simple to use a `RelativeLayout`(or even a LinearLayout could do) with two `textviews`. Give ihat layout a background which makes it look like a button. And then, add an `OnClickListener` to the layout.

Answer (score 0):

Anything wrong with using the gravity?

```
android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
```