# Setting a font for an entire layout in android

Tags: android, layout, fonts

I've been fooling around with custom fonts in Android. I know how to import a font and have a text view set to that font. I've noticed that once you have many textViews, this can become rather tedious.

Is there anyway to set an entire layouts font type to a certain font face?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973270/using-a-custom-typeface-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did was declare my own sub-class of TextView where I set the typeface in the constructor like this:

```
public class MyTextView extends TextView {

public MyTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    setTypeFace();
}


public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setTypeFace();
}


public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    setTypeFace();
}

public void setTypeFace()
{
    this.setTypeface(StaticUtils.getDefaultFontNormal(getContext()));
}

}
```

Then in my layouts, if I use the fully qualified name, it works:

```
<ca.mycompany.mobile.ui.support.MyTextView
        android:id="@+id/title_summaryreports"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="10dip"
            android:paddingTop="10dip"
            android:text="@string/title_strategies"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#ff0000" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method, Just pass top level viewgroups id and font typeface to this method and this will set font to your entire layout.

```
public void setFont(ViewGroup group, Typeface lTypeface)
{
    int count = group.getChildCount();
    View v;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        v = group.getChildAt(i);
        if (v instanceof TextView)
        {
            ((TextView) v).setTypeface(lTypeface);
        } else if (v instanceof EditText)
        {
            ((EditText) v).setTypeface(lTypeface);
        } else if (v instanceof Button)
        {
            ((Button) v).setTypeface(lTypeface);
        } else if (v instanceof TextInputLayout)
        {
            ((TextInputLayout) v).setTypeface(lTypeface);
        } else if (v instanceof ViewGroup)
            setFont((ViewGroup) v, lTypeface);
    }
}
```