# Android - Fonts in Application

Tags: android, fonts

I have added an external font in /assets directory, and manually doing setFacetype(font).
Isn't there a general way to set the whole application to use a specific font if you have added it external? Or do you have to use Android's selected fonts in order to achieve this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711858/is-it-possible-to-set-font-for-entire-application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **cannot** use your **custom fonts** through to whole application in a general way.

You **cannot** set your **custom fonts** through xml files.

You have to use the `Typeface` functions in your code to use your custom fonts within your application.

Comment: you CAN set your custom fonts in xml, you just need to override the TextView, full code and examples here: http://helpmeco.de/2012/2/custom-fonts-in-android-widgets

Comment: That code is actually setting the font via TypeFace functions so still you cannot set a custom font for default views from xml.

Comment: It's setting via the TypeFace functions in the overridden TextView widget which pulls it from xml.  You could just default the typeface if nothing was specified in the XML.

Answer (score 2):

```
tv=(TextView)findViewById(res);
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "MYFONT.TTF"); 
tv.setTypeface(font);
```

This also how to use it in a textview.

For whole application go to  [Using a custom typeface in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973270/using-a-custom-typeface-in-android).

and go to Manish Singla answer

Comment: dude he knows how to set read full question before answer it.

Answer (score 2):

```
Typeface mTypeface =  Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "YOUR FONT NAME");
textview.setTypeface(mTypeface, Typeface.NORMAL);
```