# Change the font of whole Android application through preference of the application

Tags: android, fonts

In my application, I provide a setting for user to change the font of the whole application.
I want when user choose one from the list, the whole application will immediately apply this font. I have search many questions related to this problem but I can't find a suitable solution. What do I have to do to achieve this? All help is appreciated!

Comment: HOw many fonts you wish to show user for selection

Comment: I have three different fonts. They appear as a list when user press Setting and choose Change font of application option.

Comment: you must create custom classes for all like TextView,EditText.etc then only you do that

Answer (score 0):

I couldnt find a solution now on.

I think the answer is

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9531442/621951

However, I am still investigating to find a solution.

I found a code may be that will be helped.

```
private void overrideFonts(final Context context, final View v) {

  try {

    if (v instanceof ViewGroup) {

      ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) v;

         for (int i = 0; i < vg.getChildCount(); i++) {

         View child = vg.getChildAt(i);

         overrideFonts(context, child);

             }
    } else if (v instanceof TextView ) {

      ((TextView) v).setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Vegur-R 0.602.otf"));

    }
   } catch (Exception e) {
  }
}
```

Comment: also this code is working, I used it. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8854794/621951)