# Enabling kannada font on the buttons

Tags: android, button, kannada

I wanted to write kannada alphabet/word on top of the button instead of english. I have stored an kgp_kbd.ttf in my assets folder. I am getting an white boxes on top of buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that if your device does not have support for that font built in. Even if you give `TypeFace` the support for those fonts is needed, else it will show boxes like that. You can put those fonts in system's fonts directory if your device is rooted.

Comment: where can i give this TypeFace in the sense in .xml file or .java class

Comment: You can refer this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973270/using-a-custom-typeface-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

check if this helps. [Character.UnicodeBlock](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Character.UnicodeBlock.html)