# How to set type face from XML?

Tags: android, android-layout

I know to set Typeface from coding like below.

```
type1=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/helveticaneueLtstd-bd.otf");
text.setTpeface(type1);
```

But it is difficult to me to set Typeface if I have more text views. How can I set the typeface from XML instead of from coding?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a custom typeface in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973270/using-a-custom-typeface-in-android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the xml layout you can only use `normal`, `sans`, `serif` and `monospace` as fonts. Any other font will have to be set in code like you did.

You could extend `TextView`(and use that class instead of the plain`TextView` in the xml layout) and implement a custom attribute that could take another font, other than the fonts I listed above.

Answer (score 0):

Hi. Sorry, you can not set custom typeface using `XML`.