# How can I set a typeface in Android?

Tags: android, textview

I have developed an Andriod RSS reader app.I have used custom listview to list RSS titles and its images.Now I want to change the font of RSS titles.How can I set typeface to my title textview?

Here is my adapter class in which I am setting the title Textview.

Adapter.java

```
public class InternationalAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader; 

    public InternationalAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
        activity = a;
        data=d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)


            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);




        TextView title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.title); // For this Textview I want to set Typeface.
        TextView date = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.artist);

        ImageView thumb_image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image);

        HashMap<String, String> news = new HashMap<String, String>();
        news = data.get(position);

        // Setting all values in listview
        title.setText(International.Title[position]);
        date.setText(International.Date[position]);
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(International.image[position], thumb_image);
        return vi;
    }
}
```

Comment: This question has been asked 100 times on SO . Why didn't you refer those?.

Comment: I know how to do it on an Activity.But this is different.

Comment: You can't do it on an activity. You can only do it on views.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using a custom typeface in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973270/using-a-custom-typeface-in-android)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this,

```
        public class InternationalAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

            private Activity activity;
            private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
            private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
            public ImageLoader imageLoader; 

            public InternationalAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
                activity = a;
                data=d;
                inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
            }

            public int getCount() {
                return data.size();
            }

            public Object getItem(int position) {
                return position;
            }

            public long getItemId(int position) {
                return position;
            }

            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View vi=convertView;
                if(convertView==null)


                    vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);




                TextView title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.title); // For this Textview I want to set Typeface.
                TextView date = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.artist);
//Added Here
        Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(
        activity.getAssets(), 
        "fonts/androidnation.ttf");
    title .setTypeface(font);

                ImageView thumb_image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image);

                HashMap<String, String> news = new HashMap<String, String>();
                news = data.get(position);

                // Setting all values in listview
                title.setText(International.Title[position]);
                date.setText(International.Date[position]);
                imageLoader.DisplayImage(International.image[position], thumb_image);
                return vi;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I used this method but in eclipse, there is an error."The method getContext() is undefined for the type InternationalAdpater"..

Comment: instead of getContext() try with activity

Answer (score 3):

Try like this

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(
    getContext().getAssets(), 
    "fonts/androidnation.ttf");
title .setTypeface(font);
```

Answer (score 3):

Source : https://segunfamisa.com/posts/custom-fonts-with-android-support-library

Setting typeface like the one below often does not work ([Android Runtime Exception font asset not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33888127/android-runtime-exception-font-asset-not-found))

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(activity.getAssets(), "fonts/montserrat_regular.ttf");
```

and can result into error like this:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Font asset not found fonts/montserrat_regular.ttf
```

You can therefore use the new way as given [here](https://segunfamisa.com/posts/custom-fonts-with-android-support-library)

## Steps:

### 1. Make a folder in resources folder in your project like `res/font` and paste your fonts there

#### You can alternatively create a font family

Font family is something that was introduced in Android, and it is used to define a group of fonts and their corresponding style. So the system can determine what font resource to use for regular, bold and italic styles and weight configurations. A typical font family looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<!-- regular -->
<font
    android:font="@font/josefinslab_regular"
    android:fontStyle="normal"
    android:fontWeight="400"

    app:font="@font/josefinslab_regular"
    app:fontStyle="normal"
    app:fontWeight="400" />

<!-- italic -->
<font
    android:font="@font/josefinslab_italic"
    android:fontStyle="italic"
    android:fontWeight="400"

    app:font="@font/josefinslab_italic"
    app:fontStyle="italic"
    app:fontWeight="400" />

</font-family>
```

#### Note

A really important thing to note is that we had to define attributes using both android and app namespaces. The app namespace is what ensures that the feature is backward compatible.

### 2. Using the font programmatically

```
Typeface typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(this, R.font.app_font);
myTextView.setTypeface(typeface);
```

Source : https://segunfamisa.com/posts/custom-fonts-with-android-support-library

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

```
EditText edittext =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed);
String path="F:\\MTCORSVA.TTF";
Typeface tf=Typeface.createFromFile(path);
edittext.setTypeface(tf);
```

you can use this:)

Answer (score 0):

use custome textview as given below and set font there

```
 public class MyTextView extends TextView{

 public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
        rotate();
    }

    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
        rotate();
    }

    public MyTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
        rotate();
    }

    private void rotate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        setSelected(true);
    }

    private void init() {
        if (!isInEditMode()) {
            Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/TrajanPro-Regular.otf");
            setTypeface(tf);
        }
    }


   }
```

and in your listview row xml means in **list_row**  layout add textview as

```
   <YourpackageName.MyTextView
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip" android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="22px"
        android:textColor="#34A4c5"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:maxWidth="220dp" 
        android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"  
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"></YourpackageName.MyTextView>
```

here more property are used u can remove which not required and in your **getview** method  define it as

```
      MyTextView title = (MyTextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.title);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library to change font on any view, only need to pass font file name with the binding xml code. https://github.com/ChathuraHettiarachchi/TypeFaced

1.textview

2.edittext

3.switch

4.toggle

5.button

6.radiobutton

7.checkbox

```
<com.chootdev.typefaced.TypeFacedTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:textView_font="YOUR_FONT_NAME.ttf/>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use this method:

```
t.setTypeface(Typeface.MONOSPACE,Typeface.BOLD);
```

Here monospace is a typeface.