# How to set typeface in listview in android

Tags: android, listview

How to set font typeface to list items .. please help me
list.class`
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

```
    // Defined Array values to show in ListView
    String[] values = new String[] { "a","b" };

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);`
```

list.xml

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO and please take a look [http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). There are lots of same type of posts found.

Comment: create adapter with textview(list item) and set typeface on texview.

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10662543/how-can-i-set-a-typeface-in-android

Comment: Sir, How to create adapter with textView for list item sir.. can please help me for this code

Comment: Can u help with simple xml file and class file sir... I am not getting clearly sir...

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the `getView()` method of your adapter:

```
final Typeface mTypeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "mytypeface.otf"); 

adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values) {
   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   ViewGroup view = (ViewGroup) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
   if(convertView == null) MyActivity.setAppFont(view, mTypeFace);
   return view;
  }
 };
```

Comment: How to give textView in listview sir..I am trying like this <ListView
        android:id="@+id/indchik"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    
   <TextView android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#ff0000"/>
    
    </ListView>

Comment: I tried ur code I am getting error in this line and here super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

Comment: Sir i am getting error in getview() method.. how to slove it

Comment: Have a look at this tutorial http://androidexample.com/Create_A_Simple_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=65&aaid=90, This will help you to understand how to create a `ListView` with `ArrayAdapter`

Comment: sir .. how to override getView() method.. please tell me