# Android Runtime Exception font asset not found

Tags: java, android, android-fonts

Here is my code and screenshot I'm trying to set custom font typeface but Runtime exception occurs font asset not found while font file is in asset folder. Am I missing something ?

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font/terminal.ttf");
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.weatherHeadingTV)).setTypeface(font);
```

[image]
[image: screenshot of android studio project]

Comment: I had a similar error. Restarting Android Studio solved it. Don't ask me why....

Comment: In my case even just restart simulator helps. Looks like a bug in android studio

Comment: Restarting Android studio (even in administrator) did not work for me, path of my folder is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried another font file that worked fine So I conclude that earlier font file was corrupt. Thanks @Miduhun MP ,  @Gowtham Raj and @jagan reddy

Answer (score 65):

Use this method :

```java
final Typeface typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.X);
```

`ResourcesCompat`  class is a compatible way to retrieve your resources.

Comment: Hey there! While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: This worked for me, should be marked as the correct answer

Comment: Best answer. Simple, on-spot

Comment: this should be the accepted answer, it's backwards compatible and avoids having magic strings

Answer (score 17):

1. Folder's name should be "fonts" and not "font"
2. Note that your "fonts" folder is located under your "assets" folder (which should be located under your "main" folder and not your "res" folder)
   It took me way too long to figure this one out...

Comment: This is the best answer. The author must accept at least one answer to help others.

Answer (score 7):

the folder name has to be **'fonts'** not 'font'

```
Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/" + font);
```

Comment: Accept the answer if the query was resolved... it ll help the community

Comment: I have renamed font folder to fonts but still same error persist.

Answer (score 5):

Your font asset folder is named incorrectly. You should name the folder as `fonts` not as `font`. Also change your code:

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/terminal.ttf");
```

Comment: I have renamed font folder to fonts but still same error persist.

Comment: @MuzammilHusnain: Looks like lollipop bug to me, check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27269264/custom-fonts-not-working-in-lollipop

Comment: This was the only answer which solved my issue. I had both "font" and "fonts" folders redundantly.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Instant Run with Android Gradle plugin version 2.2.0-alphaX, it is a known bug.

A workaround is to turn of Instant Run until the issue is resolved.

You can track it here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=212849&can=1&q=subcomponent%3DTools-Studio%20-has%3Aproject%20attachments%3D0&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened&start=7700

Answer (score 3):

worked for me

```
typefaceRegular = ResourcesCompat.getFont(mContext, R.font.sarala_regular);
            tv_bs_priceRange.setTypeface(typefaceRegular);
```

Answer (score 2):

Common error when you have assets in your project and you are using the alpha versions of AS. This appears to be a bug in the Android studio build system. A simple workaround is to clean the project before you run it and that should solve the issue that you are facing.

Comment: Cleaning the project fixed the issue! : )

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and managed to fix it. Originally I thought the font files were corrupt but they weren't. Then I thought Android Studio didn't like `.ttf` files, because they were the only ones not working. Turns out it's nothing wrong with the fonts.

FIX: Just click `Build > Clean project`. Fixed it straight away for me.

Answer (score 0):

Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(),"font/terminal.ttf");

((TextView) findViewById(R.id.weatherHeadingTV)).setTypeface(typeface);

Answer (score 0):

If you use AndroidAnnotations, in app build.gradle, verify if assets folder is ok: ex: main/src/assets.

If you change de font, uninstall your app from your device/emulator, and run again.

Code:

```
public static void setFontFace(Context context, TextView textView) {
  Typeface type = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "myfont.ttf");
  textView.setTypeface(type);
}
```

Comment: Am using above code but same error raised as "Font asset not found".File exist in assets and assets/fonts

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem that .woff fonts are not accepted on Android 7+. So i switched to .ttf fonts.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the font file itself was corrupted. I tried another one to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to access fonts just like this:

val font =ResourcesCompat.getFont(requireContext(), R.font.inter_light)

Answer (score -3):

I have looked into all the answer but none of them worked for me.
I found a new solution after reading the documentation.
Here are the steps to follow:

1. Go to file menu
2. In new, go to Folder and create assets folder
3. Paste your font file in this assets folder
4. Use in your code using Typeface attribute.

   Typeface type = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "myfont.ttf");
   textView.setTypeface(type);

Now, you are all set to use the fonts you like.

Comment: gives null pointer exception. i am stuck with this for about a week