# android studio cannot find custom font file

Tags: android, android-assets, android-fonts

I am using a simple `TextView` in my activity and want to make it appear in a custom font 'Black Chancery'. I have put the `blkchcry.ttf` file at location **app>src>main>assets>fonts>blkchcry.ttf**. But, the android studio can't find that font. Here's my `AboutusActivity.java` code

```
public class AboutusActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_aboutus);

    TextView tx = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.title);
    Typeface custom_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),  "fonts/blkchcry.ttf");
    tx.setTypeface(custom_font);
    }
}
```

and following is the `activity_aboutus.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".AboutusActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="About Rathi Classes"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/about_text"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and here is the logcat

```
Process: net.softglobe.rathiclasses, PID: 8894
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.softglobe.rathiclasses/net.softglobe.rathiclasses.AboutusActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Font asset not found fonts/blkchcry.ttf
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Font asset not found fonts/blkchcry.ttf
    at android.graphics.Typeface.createFromAsset(Typeface.java:206)
    at net.softglobe.rathiclasses.AboutusActivity.onCreate(AboutusActivity.java:17)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

I have tried cleaning the project but it failed to resolve the problem. Please help.

Comment: wild guess here, are there special permissions on the file or something? does it work if you specify the exact file patch on the machine, rather than relative asset path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paste Font here like this and also make your font name in small case
:-

```
app  > src > main > assets > fonts > blkchry.tff
```

set Font in java File like this :-

```
public class AboutusActivity extends Activity {
 Context mContext;
 Typeface fontblkchry;

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mContext = this;
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_about_us);

      fontblkchry = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(), "fonts/blkchry.ttf");
      textview1.setTypeface(fontblkchry);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try this above snippet. i already using in my all project like this and it's 100% working

Comment: @InsaneCat I have already told, `mContext` gives an error `cannot resolve symbol`

Comment: Declaring global variables won't help. LOL!

Comment: check spelling is it correrct "fonts" capital/small ?

Comment: @InsaneCat what is `mContext`? It gives me an error.

Comment: @Strooks42 Check Updated Answer plz

Comment: @InsaneCat tried it, but unfortunately the log says `Font asset not found fonts/blkchcry.ttf`

Comment: first clean your project may be your font file is corrupted tried another font.

Comment: see below link:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33888127/android-runtime-exception-font-asset-not-found

Comment: @InsaneCat  check my answer please.

Comment: @InsaneCat Your answer was just right! worked for me! Maybe there is a problem in that file. I have downloaded the file from another website and it worked fine. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Change the location your `blkchcry.tttf` 
from

`app>src>main>assets>fonts>blkchcry.ttf.`

to

> `app>src>main>res>font>blkchry.tff`

And here's the fun part, 
you need to create a custom font file inside the same folder.
Name it as `my_font.xml`

That's called **Creating a Font Family**

If you’re using multiple versions of the same font, then you may want to group them together into a font family. A font family is essentially a dedicated XML file where you define each version of the font, along with its associated style and weight attributes.

Here's a demo font file

[**Update**] which you can simply paste coz I updated the contents.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <font
        android:font="@font/blkchry"
        android:fontStyle="normal"
        android:fontWeight="400"
        app:font="@font/blkchry"
        app:fontStyle="normal"
        app:fontWeight="400"
        tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute" />

</font-family>
```

Because `getAssets()` will look for an `.xml` file, not `.tff` even though you mentioned `.tff` file in your code.

Comment: I have tried by moving file location from **app>src>main>assets>fonts>blkchcry.ttf** to **app>src>main>res>font>blkchry.tff** and changed the code to `TextView tx = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.title);
        Typeface custom_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),  "font/blkchcry.ttf"); //replaced 'fonts' with 'font'
        tx.setTypeface(custom_font);` but not worked

Comment: Try rebuilding the project. Perhaps it will help.

Comment: I have rebuild the project, cleaned it, and put the .ttf file on both location. But unfortunately, didn't worked. App still stopping

Answer (score 0):

Change your location:

from

```
app>src>main>assets>fonts>blkchcry.ttf.
```

to

```
app>src>main>res>font>blkchry.tff
```

then change your typeface:

```
 Typeface typeface = getResources().getFont(R.font.blkchcry); textView.setTypeface(typeface);
```

See more details: *https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml*

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was adding a font with Capital Letters and some symbols like -(hyphen).
Try renaming the fonts.
So, just make all letters small, replace hyphen with underscore _