# How can i use clocktopia font which is already there in my Android Device?

Tags: android, android-fonts

I have a `clocktopia` font on my android device and it's only on some applications.

**How do I use that particular font programmatically?**

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, put the .ttf (or other font file) in your /assets directory.
Then, set the font face of your textview with the following code.

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromFile("path-to-file"); 
textView.setTypeface(font);
```

Unfortunately you cannot use custom typefaces in XML (so you also cannot define a custom theme with your font).

Comment: How do I find the font on my Android? Do you know which dir it will be in?

Comment: I was wrong about fonts outside of the apk, and updated my answer as well.  
If you know the path, you can use [Typeface.createFromFile(String path)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Typeface.html#createFromFile(java.lang.String))

I'm not sure where Clocktopia is located on a device. I would probably just try to find the .ttf and put it in my apk.  
Also, you may want to check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973270/using-a-custom-typeface-in-android), which has some more solutions on how to use custom fonts.

Answer (score 0):

[Custom fonts and XML layouts (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376250/custom-fonts-and-xml-layouts-android)

You can use the TextViewPlus class provider here to load the typeface from xml but I don't know of a way to use a theme to do this automatically.