# How to set Custom Font in whole Application in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to show my own custom font ".ttf" in my whole application

Please Note...
I don't need to change only, "Text view", "Edit text" and "Button" text font by creating Typeface

Comment: this can be done only Text view and Edit text

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973270/using-a-custom-typeface-in-android/16275257#16275257

Comment: @andruboy The second link is styling. Does that allow choosing a "`customfont.ttf`" in assets folder? :)

Answer (score 2):

The only way out is to extend the Android UI widgets and create custom views. But that's a tedious process. Instead, you can use [Calligraphy Project](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy):

> Calligraphy
>   Custom fonts in Android the easy way.
>
> Are you fed up of Custom views to set fonts? Or traversing the
>   ViewTree to find TextViews? Yeah me too.

You can refer to these answers for more
[Android - Using Custom Font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651086/android-using-custom-font)

*the following links have been taken from the comments:*
[Using a custom typeface in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973270/using-a-custom-typeface-in-android/16275257)
[How to set default font family for entire Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16404820/how-to-set-default-font-family-for-entire-android-app)

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a custom font style in your manifest.xml file under your application tag.
For Example:-

```xml
    <application
            android:name="com.digimedia.icouch.bean.AppContext"
            android:icon="@drawable/app_logo"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme" >
```