# Get Font from textview/edittext

Tags: android, fonts

How to get font which is currently used in textview/edittext? I don't set custom font but need to know which font android uses to show me the text in textview: Noto, Roboto, Noto CJK or SansSerif Hebrew and etc.

Comment: getTypeface() will help you.

Comment: I tried it and received null.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your question.
If you have not used `setTypeFace()` you will recive `null`
the default TypeFace for a T`extView` or `Button` is defined in the `style.xml`.
Something like:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
  <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/RobotoTextViewStyle</item>
  <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/RobotoButtonStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="RobotoTextViewStyle" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-light</item>
</style>
```

Check this questions [Default Font-Family for App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16404820/how-to-set-default-font-family-for-entire-android-app) , [Default font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711858/is-it-possible-to-set-font-for-entire-application)

I tried it myself and you are right, it returns `null`
seems like typeFace change the default attributes but the attriburtes wich the view is started with are not directly interpreted as a `typeFace`

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried calling `getTypeface()` in your `TextView` before you change it and store the result somewhere?
[Check this link, this will help you](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getTypeface())

Comment: I used default hello world sample. I get TextView through findView by id and call getTypeface from textview. That's it.

Comment: Have you checked the link mate. It contains one property for getTypeface(). i.e fontFamily. Take a look at it.

Comment: I've looked at your link. It doesn't make sense to me: textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
Typeface typeface = textView.getTypeface();<- this is null

Comment: Let me know how to get Font Family name (String) from typeface. Typeface doesn't have fontFamily member.