# Change the font of entire app all textview, including buttons and edittexts

Tags: android, android-fonts

I want to change the app font to `roboto`. I have tried [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711858/is-it-possible-to-set-font-for-entire-application) also.

But it is changing only the textview font, not changing the listview adapter XML font.

How do I change the entire app font to `roboto`?

Comment: @playmaker420 user already mentioned this link in question. 
@
That is best answer ever, may be you using default layout for listview row so you have to create custom row layout then it will work.

Comment: I missed the the link

Comment: @testangain see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16404820/how-to-set-default-font-family-for-entire-android-app

Comment: have u solved ur problem?

Comment: @roon13 i have tried this but roboto font is not available as the default in android

Comment: @krishna  my problem is not yet solved please suggest me possible solutions

Comment: In adapter views not setting roboto font typeface, otherthan working right?

Comment: yes in activity xml it is showing me the font

Comment: How to ur creating LayoutInfrater object in adapter?

Comment: LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
         rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_alert, null);
         // configure view holder
         ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
         viewHolder.textMessage = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.alertMsg);

Comment: In my case, it is working for adapter also, if u want i updated my answer

Comment: @testangaintestig you have to include the roboto

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put this in your style.xml

```
<style name="RobotoTextViewStyle" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
<item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-light</item>
</style>
```

also you have to change this.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
<item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/RobotoTextViewStyle</item>
```

Developer site has provided information on this. 
Let me know the progress

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the content view / or any view group to this function and a typeface.

```
public void replaceFonts(ViewGroup viewTree, TypeFace typeface) {
    Stack<ViewGroup> stackOfViewGroup = new Stack<ViewGroup>();
    stackOfViewGroup.push(viewTree);
    while (!stackOfViewGroup.isEmpty()) {
        ViewGroup tree = stackOfViewGroup.pop();
        for (int i = 0; i < tree.getChildCount(); i++) {
            View child = tree.getChildAt(i);
            if (child instanceof ViewGroup) {
                // recursive call
                stackOfViewGroup.push((ViewGroup) child);
            }else if (child instanceof Button) {
              ((Button) child).setTypeface(typeface);
            }else if (child instanceof EditText) {
               ((EditText) child).setTypeface(typeface);
            } else if (child instanceof TextView) {
                // base case
                ((TextView) child).setTypeface(typeface);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or create a custom Button, EditText,TextView .and add it to view group. Search for FontTextView on Google.