# Set default font family for Android app

Tags: android, android-fonts

I'm new to Android studio and I am wondering where to set the default font family for Android app in Android studio after reading the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16404820/how-to-set-default-font-family-for-entire-android-app).

I have tried to put the code in `activity_main.xml` and `AndroidManifest.xml` but it does not work.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: you will find style.xml in value folder add font style in your theme and than pass tis style in manifest application theme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks KDeogharkar!

Looks like I would have to add the code inside of `styles.xml` in `values` folder. It worked :)

Answer (score 1):

/res/values*/themes.xml

Pick any parent theme to extend here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/RobotoFont</item>
</style>
<style name="RobotoFont" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

Then in your app manifest

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme`"
```

Comment: android:fontFamily exists in api 16 and above only

Comment: this will now be available in google support font library starting 26.0.1