# How to set default font family in React Native?

Tags: react-native

Is there an equivalent to this CSS in React Native, so that the app uses the same  font everywhere ?

```
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
}
```

Applying it manually on every Text node seems overly complicated.

Comment: [Is there a way to set a font globally in React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51023593/is-there-a-way-to-set-a-font-globally-in-react-native) has a few additional approaches.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

The recommended way is to create your own component, such as MyAppText. MyAppText would be a simple component that renders a Text component using your universal style and can pass through other props, etc.

https://reactnative.dev/docs/text#limited-style-inheritance

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I needed. Seems like I didn't grasp the component approach deeply enough yet :)

Comment: One thing that's not super clear from the docs is how to pass through properties in your component and to respect styles on your component. You can do so like this: https://gist.github.com/neilsarkar/c9b5fc7e67bbbe4c407eec17deb7311e

Comment: @NeilSarkar One problem with that gist example is that the style is generated in the constructor. As a result, if the style prop changes, you would want it to re-render, but in this case it won't. It should be handled in `render()` instead of the constructor. Using hooks with `useMemo` could also help if efficiency is important. 

Alternatively, if you want to keep it in the constructor, it's important to add a `componentDidUpdate` logic  that updates `this.style` when the component updates due to a style prop change.

Comment: good point, thanks! looks like someone added a refactored version to the gist too that combines the styles in the render method (of a pure component, in their case)

Comment: For me, positioning children isn't working. For example `alignSelf: "center"` does not work ...

Answer (score 73):

There was recently a node module that was made that solves this problem so you **don't** have to **create another component**.

https://github.com/Ajackster/react-native-global-props

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-global-props

The documentation states that in your highest order component, import the `setCustomText` function like so.

```
import { setCustomText } from 'react-native-global-props';
```

Then, create the custom styling/props you want for the react-native `Text` component. In your case, you'd like *fontFamily* to work on every `Text` component.

```
const customTextProps = { 
  style: { 
    fontFamily: yourFont
  }
}
```

Call the `setCustomText` function and pass your props/styles into the function.

```
setCustomText(customTextProps);
```

And then all react-native `Text` components will have your declared *fontFamily* along with any other props/styles you provide.

Comment: The idiomatic method to use component composition seems like a better choice, although this is a cool hack.

Comment: When the Text component doesn't support changing default fonts out of the box, this solution becomes much better. I would much rather add a global control in one place and use the native components than make a wrapper component for every detail that true native apps provide.

Comment: I hesitated between above 2 solutions, actually I hate to install unofficial plugins cause react-native itself continues to change, but finally I choose this one as it can really save me huge amount of time. Thanks!

Comment: SO I need to call `<Text style={styles.text}>` ??
It's not perfect solution like thats `body {font-family: 'Open Sans';}`

have any update solution ??

Comment: No you don't need to do `Text style={styles.text}>`. You just need to declare your custom props somewhere in your application and it will be applied to all of your Text components. It's very similar to `body {font-family: ....}`

Comment: This is golden approach, but how can this be done in RN Expo project?

Comment: IMO react-native-global-props is less of a hack than wrapping every single component and having to maintain those wrappers.   Thanks @Ajackster for sharing your very useful library.

Answer (score 39):

For React Native 0.56.0+ check if defaultProps is defined first:

```
Text.defaultProps = Text.defaultProps || {}
```

Then add:

```
Text.defaultProps.style =  { fontFamily: 'some_font' }
```

Add the above in the constructor of the App.js file (or any root component you have).

In order to override the style you can create a style object and spread it then add your additional style 
(e.g `{ ...baseStyle, fontSize: 16 }`)

Comment: Maybe the `defaultProps` didn't exist when all the other answers were written but this seem to be the way to do it now.

Comment: Unfortunately, it won't work if we override `style` prop, say, to tweak styles of particular `Text` components

Comment: True but you can work around this , create the common style as an object and when ever you want some custom font just pass to the component an array that contains that object + yourNewStyleObject @Amerzilla

Comment: @A-J-A thanks! It'll work, although adds small overhead :)

Comment: I've found that I can use `spread operator` to combine text styles and avoid creating arrays in `render`
```js
textStyle: {
    ...baseStyle,
    fontSize: 16
}
```

Comment: There is a problem there. If someone then define the `style` prop in the Text component, the default font is going to be replaced.

Comment: Cannot set property 'style' of undefined

Comment: @jamesmurphy probably now you have to check first if its there: 

Text.defaultProps = Text.defaultProps || {}
Text.defaultProps.style = { ... }

Comment: Yes that got rid of the error, but does not appear to work on app (font does not change)....Im testing on Android and using RN 0.59.5

Comment: constructor in App.js (base component)

Comment: it's 2019 and it's working perfectly. just remember in android you can't use "-" in file names. define your font file names something like font_name.ttf.

Comment: This is *one* way of doing it @AniruddhaShevle

Comment: @A-J-A: I know. My question still remains the same! Is this the right way to do it? What do you think?

Comment: It depends on your approach because this has a bit of drawbacks ( styles can get overridden then you'll have to spread that object into the component style prop ).
 If you don't face that problem, this approach is simple and  straightforward. I can't really say that this is the RIGHT way because I would be indirectly saying other ways are wrong.  @AniruddhaShevle

Answer (score 29):

You can override Text behaviour by adding this in any of your component using Text:

```
let oldRender = Text.prototype.render;
Text.prototype.render = function (...args) {
    let origin = oldRender.call(this, ...args);
    return React.cloneElement(origin, {
        style: [{color: 'red', fontFamily: 'Arial'}, origin.props.style]
    });
};
```

Edit: since React Native 0.56, `Text.prototype`is not working anymore. You need to remove the `.prototype` :

```
let oldRender = Text.render;
Text.render = function (...args) {
    let origin = oldRender.call(this, ...args);
    return React.cloneElement(origin, {
        style: [{color: 'red', fontFamily: 'Arial'}, origin.props.style]
    });
};
```

Comment: That's a great solution but you have to change: [origin.props.style, {color: 'red', fontFamily: 'Arial'}] ->[{color: 'red', fontFamily: 'Arial'}, origin.props.style]  

Otherwise you will override the custom style setted in the component

Comment: Worked best. Text.prototype.render doesn't work anymore, Text.render does !

Comment: how to avoid icons inheriting the same?

Comment: I agree with @IaconisSimone Best approach to set fontFamily and to be sure not to override custom styles

Comment: Do I need to restart the app, if I want to make it dynamically ?

Comment: I tried the same thing for TextInput but it didn't work :/ any ideas?

Comment: This is the way to go

Comment: But this also changes some of the fonts in the warning and error boxes of RN in dev mode. The RN code does not specifically sets text color on some of its renderings. So be careful with custom colours here.

Comment: this doens't work anymore

Answer (score 21):

With React-Native 0.56, the above method of changing `Text.prototype.render` does not work anymore, so you have to use your own component, which can be done in one line!

MyText.js

```js
export default props => <Text {...props} style={[{fontFamily: 'Helvetica'}, props.style]}>{props.children}</Text>
```

AnotherComponent.js

```js
import Text from './MyText';

...
<Text>This will show in default font.</Text>
...
```

Comment: @FancyJohn It will now with hooks and `useRef`. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref

Comment: Text.prototype.render has changed to Text.render.

Answer (score 11):

Add this function to your root `App` component and then run it from your constructor after adding your font using these instructions. https://medium.com/react-native-training/react-native-custom-fonts-ccc9aacf9e5e

```js
import {Text, TextInput} from 'react-native'

SetDefaultFontFamily = () => {
    let components = [Text, TextInput]

    const customProps = {
        style: {
            fontFamily: "Rubik"
        }
    }

    for(let i = 0; i < components.length; i++) {
        const TextRender = components[i].prototype.render;
        const initialDefaultProps = components[i].prototype.constructor.defaultProps;
        components[i].prototype.constructor.defaultProps = {
            ...initialDefaultProps,
            ...customProps,
        }
        components[i].prototype.render = function render() {
            let oldProps = this.props;
            this.props = { ...this.props, style: [customProps.style, this.props.style] };
            try {
                return TextRender.apply(this, arguments);
            } finally {
                this.props = oldProps;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, didn't want to install anything more.

Comment: If my App.js mainly consists of `const App = StackNavigator({...})` and `export default App` where exactly would I place this code as I do not think I can use a constructor here?

Comment: I have added my own question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50081042/adding-a-default-font-when-using-stacknavigator-in-react-native

Comment: Why constructor over componentDidMount?

Comment: This failed to work for me starting with RN0.67, however adding a `arguments[0] = props;` before the try block fixed it for me.

Answer (score 6):

Super late to this thread but here goes.

TLDR;  Add the following block in your `AppDelegate.m`

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

 ....
    // HERE: replace "Verlag" with your font
  [[UILabel appearance] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Verlag" size:17.0]];
  ....
}
```

### Walkthrough of the whole flow.

A few ways you can do this outside of using a plugin like `react-native-global-props` so Ill walk you though step by step.

### Adding fonts to platforms.

#### How to add the font to IOS project

First let's create a location for our assets.
Let's make the following directory at our root.

```

```
ios/
static/
       fonts/
```

```

Now let's add a "React Native" NPM in our package.json

```
  "rnpm": {
    "static": [
   "./static/fonts/"
    ]
  }
```

Now we can run "react-native link" to add our assets to our native apps.

#### Verifying or doing manually.

That should add your font names into the projects `.plist`
(for VS code users run `code ios/*/Info.plist` to confirm)

Here let's assume `Verlag` is the font you added, it should look something like this:

```
     <dict>
   <plist>
      .....
      <key>UIAppFonts</key>
      <array>
         <string>Verlag Bold Italic.otf</string>
         <string>Verlag Book Italic.otf</string>
         <string>Verlag Light.otf</string>
         <string>Verlag XLight Italic.otf</string>
         <string>Verlag XLight.otf</string>
         <string>Verlag-Black.otf</string>
         <string>Verlag-BlackItalic.otf</string>
         <string>Verlag-Bold.otf</string>
         <string>Verlag-Book.otf</string>
         <string>Verlag-LightItalic.otf</string>
      </array>
      ....    
</dict>
</plist>
```

Now that you mapped them, now let's make sure they are actually there and being loaded (this is also how you'd do it manually).

Go to `"Build Phase" > "Copy Bundler Resource"`, If it didn't work you'll a manually add under them here.

[image: 1_uuz0__3kx2vvguz37bhvya]

## Get Font Names (recognized by XCode)

First open your XCode logs, like:

[image: XXXX]

Then you can add the following block in your `AppDelegate.m` to log the names of the Fonts and the Font Family.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    .....


  for (NSString* family in [UIFont familyNames])
  {
    NSLog(@"%@", family);
    for (NSString* name in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName: family])
    {
      NSLog(@" %@", name);
    }
  }

  ...
}
```

Once you run you should find your fonts if loaded correctly, here we found ours in logs like this:

```
2018-05-07 10:57:04.194127-0700 MyApp[84024:1486266] Verlag
2018-05-07 10:57:04.194266-0700 MyApp[84024:1486266]  Verlag-Book
2018-05-07 10:57:04.194401-0700 MyApp[84024:1486266]  Verlag-BlackItalic
2018-05-07 10:57:04.194516-0700 MyApp[84024:1486266]  Verlag-BoldItalic
2018-05-07 10:57:04.194616-0700 MyApp[84024:1486266]  Verlag-XLight
2018-05-07 10:57:04.194737-0700 MyApp[84024:1486266]  Verlag-Bold
2018-05-07 10:57:04.194833-0700 MyApp[84024:1486266]  Verlag-Black
2018-05-07 10:57:04.194942-0700 MyApp[84024:1486266]  Verlag-XLightItalic
2018-05-07 10:57:04.195170-0700 MyApp[84024:1486266]  Verlag-LightItalic
2018-05-07 10:57:04.195327-0700 MyApp[84024:1486266]  Verlag-BookItalic
2018-05-07 10:57:04.195510-0700 MyApp[84024:1486266]  Verlag-Light
```

So now we know it loaded the `Verlag` family and are the fonts inside that family

- `Verlag-Book`
- `Verlag-BlackItalic`
- `Verlag-BoldItalic`
- `Verlag-XLight`
- `Verlag-Bold`
- `Verlag-Black`
- `Verlag-XLightItalic`
- `Verlag-LightItalic`
- `Verlag-BookItalic`
- `Verlag-Light`

These are now the case sensitive names we can use in our font family we can use in our react native app.

## Got -'em now set default font.

Then to set a default font to add your font family name in your  `AppDelegate.m` with this line

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

 ....
    // ADD THIS LINE (replace "Verlag" with your font)

  [[UILabel appearance] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Verlag" size:17.0]];
  ....
}
```

Done.

Comment: The best approach, but is not working, anything related to the las update of RN 0.57?

Comment: For android this answer worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54696464/714936

Answer (score 4):

For about a year I was using the `react-native-global-props` library mentioned in the 2nd comment to set a global font throughout the app. It was working great, and it felt better than using custom text components everywhere.

Suddenly the global font stopped working after I updated react native. I realized that the `react-native-global-props` library has not been updated since 2018.

I found this alternative package: `react-native-simple-default-props`
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-simple-default-props

Followed the docs exactly, and it worked perfectly after I was stuck on the best way to do this for several hours. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Thanks for this!  I only worry that it will also become out of date as it's already on 2 years since the last update.  But for now (RN 0.72.6) seems to work as it should.

Answer (score 2):

For android, this is works for me.

Create a folder called font inside

> android\app\src\main\res\

Insert your font.ttf/.otf inside the font folder, Make sure the font name is lower case letters and underscore only.

> eg:- rubik_regular.ttf

Add below line in

> android\app\src\main\res\values\styles.xml

```
<item name="android:fontFamily">@font/font_name</item>
```

for example,

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/rubik_regular</item>
    </style>

    ...

</resources>
```

Make sure to re-run your app.

Also, we can add font size and font colors like this

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#008</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/rubik_regular</item>
    </style>

    ...

</resources>
```

Comment: Have you tested it? On RN 0.66 it breaks text layout.

Comment: I did a small project. `"react-native": "^0.66.3"`

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47350760/5289334) used to work for me when I was using `v0.63`. But after upgrading `react-native` to `v0.66.4` it broke.

I think the implementation of `Text` component has changed.

I came up with this solution:

```
    const oldTextRender = Text.render;

    Text.render = function(...args) {
        const origin = oldTextRender.call(this, ...args);
        const children = origin.props.children;

        if (typeof children === 'object') {
            return React.cloneElement(origin, {
                children: React.cloneElement(children, {
                    style: [ { fontFamily: 'CustomFontFamily' }, children.props.style ]
                })
            });
        }

        return React.cloneElement(origin, {
            style: [ { fontFamily: 'CustomFontFamily' }, origin.props.style ]
        });
    };
```

Notice that `children` prop may be an `object`, for example it might be a `LogBoxMessage` component. But the type of `children` prop of normal texts that are rendered on the screen are as type of `string`.

You may want to use a recursive function to apply the `fontFamily` to `children`

Answer (score 1):

To have default font styling without styling `LogBox`, see:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Text } from 'react-native'

import yourStyle from './yourStyle'

export default function setGlobalFontFamily() {
  const oldTextRender = Text.render

  Text.render = function (...args) {
    const origin = oldTextRender.call(this, ...args)

    // RCTVirtualText is being used for LogBox while RCTText is being used for normal text
    if (origin.type === 'RCTVirtualText') {
      return origin
    }

    const children = origin.props.children
    if (typeof children === 'object') {
      return React.cloneElement(origin, {
        children: React.cloneElement(children, {
          style: [yourStyle, children.props.style]
        })
      })
    }

    return React.cloneElement(origin, {
      style: [yourStyle, origin.props.style]
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That works for me:
[Add Custom Font in React Native](https://blog.bam.tech/developper-news/add-a-custom-font-to-your-react-native-app)

download your fonts and place them in assets/fonts folder, add this line in package.json

```
 "rnpm": {
"assets": ["assets/fonts/Sarpanch"]}
```

then open terminal and run this command: **react-native link**

Now your are good to go. For more detailed step. visit the link above mentioned

Answer (score 0):

For React Native version ≥ 0.60, in your root file create a file called `react-native.config.js` and put the followings, then just run `react-native link`

```
module.exports = {
  assets: ["./assets/fonts"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating a theme for your application, you can use a React native ui library such as Nativebase to achieve what you are looking for and you can create your custom theme or component as well.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Add

```
"rnpm": {
  "assets": [
 "./assets/fonts/"
  ]
}
```

in `package.json`
 then run `react-native link`

Answer (score -2):

Set in package.json

```
"rnpm": {
  "assets": [
     "./assets/fonts/"
  ]
}
```

And link react-native link