# how to change the font size depending on the language in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, internationalization

I'm using the i18n-js and the react-native-localize to support multiple languages in my React Native application. I create a JSON file for each language and display it with a key depending on the user's language settings. Here is the core file that imports JSON files and configures the i18n.

```js
import I18n from 'i18n-js';
import * as RNLocalize from 'react-native-localize';

import en from './en.json';
import ja from './ja.json';

const locales = RNLocalize.getLocales();

if (Array.isArray(locales)) {
  I18n.locale = locales[0].languageTag;
}

I18n.fallbacks = true;
I18n.translations = {
  en,
  ja
};

export default I18n;
```

Since some languages don't use alphabets, I want to be able to change its font size.

Does anyone know how I can make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Check this post [How to set default font family in React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35255645/how-to-set-default-font-family-in-react-native)
Answer 1 and 2 is the response to your question.
The question is for font family but it's the same for the font-size, you just need to adjust depending of the langage of your user.