# Default font for an Android app

Tags: android, android-fonts

This is a follow up for this question:

[How to set default font family for entire Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16404820/how-to-set-default-font-family-for-entire-android-app)

I got some custom fonts which I added to assets/fonts folder. Now I want to use a font in that library to be the default one for the entire application.

The accepted answer for the linked question above suggests using a style which is what I want, but with the attribute `"android:fontFamily"` which was only added as of API 16. Is there a way to use a style for older APIs as well?

Comment: u need only one font for entire app?  or bold , small or other font also?

Comment: You can use custom views and define your font in that. This way by changin font in one class will change it in entire class

Comment: I want to make a custom font I got the default everywhere and change manually wherever I need to use a bold font etc.

Comment: And I prefer a solution not involving extending a class. Its possible but I prefer a style first if possible

Comment: Calligraphy Library   library is your solution but it cant accept "android:fontFamily"  this tag   instead of it u can use "fontpath:"yrfont""

Comment: I actually looked into that as well, but I got another problem that due to a very old project, I'm using Eclipse so I need that library for Eclipse, but its available with Gradle only

Comment: you can take project directly from github

Comment: "Is there a way to use a style for older APIs as well?" -- no.

Comment: @YonatanNir  look i have add .aar File for eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I eventually did was to first add this class:

```
public class TypefaceUtil 
{

/**
 * Using reflection to override default typeface
 * NOTICE: DO NOT FORGET TO SET TYPEFACE FOR APP THEME AS DEFAULT TYPEFACE WHICH WILL BE OVERRIDDEN
 *
 * @param context                    to work with assets
 * @param defaultFontNameToOverride  for example "monospace"
 * @param customFontFileNameInAssets file name of the font from assets
 */
public static void overrideFont(Context context, String defaultFontNameToOverride, String customFontFileNameInAssets) 
{
    final Typeface customFontTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), customFontFileNameInAssets);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) 
    {
        Map<String, Typeface> newMap = new HashMap<String, Typeface>();
        newMap.put("serif", customFontTypeface);
        try 
        {
            final Field staticField = Typeface.class.getDeclaredField("sSystemFontMap");
            staticField.setAccessible(true);
            staticField.set(null, newMap);
        } 
        catch (NoSuchFieldException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (IllegalAccessException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        try 
        {
            final Field defaultFontTypefaceField = Typeface.class.getDeclaredField(defaultFontNameToOverride);
            defaultFontTypefaceField.setAccessible(true);
            defaultFontTypefaceField.set(null, customFontTypeface);
        } catch (Exception e) 
        {
            Log.e(TypefaceUtil.class.getSimpleName(), "Can not set custom font " + customFontFileNameInAssets + " instead of " + defaultFontNameToOverride);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Then I just added this line in the `Application` class:

```
@Override
public void onCreate()
{
    super.onCreate();
    TypefaceUtil.overrideFont(getApplicationContext(), "serif", "fonts/Ubuntu-Regular.ttf");
}
```

The `fonts` directory which holds the fonts themselves is inside the `assets` directory which is inside `src\main` (`src\main\assets\fonts`)

Answer (score 1):

If you want a default font for your android App you can use:

[Calligraphy Library](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy)

and you need to initialize it from your application class once you do that the custom font will be applicable for all the activities of the app.

Just follow the lib wiki to setup it.

Comment: read first   react after    the man told that he need  "android:fontFamily"

Comment: I actually looked into that as well, but I got another problem that due to a very old project, I'm using Eclipse so I need that library for Eclipse as well

Answer (score 1):

I tried searching for a solution and found out that you cannot add a custom font as the default font for lower versions that is less than 16.
It works for in built fonts though.
Here is a possible [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16404820/how-to-set-default-font-family-for-entire-android-app)

Answer (score 1):

For  `"android:fontFamily"`
- only accepted default fonts provide by your `OS version`  [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13329907/3513479).
- after  **Android "O"**  you can use it with your **resources** folder [LINK](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/working-with-fonts.html)

So,

If You have **existing** project  best and quicker way to set font in your app is [Calligraphy Library](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy)  suggest by @Oussaki.

```
<TextView
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    fontPath="fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf"/>
```

it reqire only  `fontPath="fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf"` after **integrate** it

And also available for [Eclipse .Aar file](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=uk/co/chrisjenx/calligraphy/2.2.0/calligraphy-2.2.0.aar)

### Edit

do not forget to put this line at your every root layout. [LINK](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy#custom-font-per-textview)

```
tools:ignore="MissingPrefix"
```

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

add font ttf file in your assets resource

try this below class custom text view and add custom class in your xml file

```
public class CustomTextView extends TextView {


    public CustomTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.setTypeface(getTypeFace(context));
    }

    public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.setTypeface(getTypeFace(context));
    }

    public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        this.setTypeface(getTypeFace(context));
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        this.setTypeface(getTypeFace(context));
    }


    public Typeface getTypeFace(Context context) {
        Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "your_filename.ttf");
        return font;
    }
}
```

In xml file like :

```
<package_name.CustomTextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_downloading"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/icon_close"
        android:textSize="100dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@color/col_white"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:visibility="visible" />
```

Comment: I prefer a solution not involving extending a class. Its possible but I prefer a style first if possible