# Can not override AppTheme font

Tags: android, fonts, android-xml

This is my AppTheme style in `style.xml`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily" tools:targetApi="jelly_bean">@font/montserrat_regular</item>
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/montserrat_regular</item>
</style>
```

and the application tag in `manifest.xml`

```
 <application
        android:name=".Amelio"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

What i want is to set fontFamily in AppTheme so i dont have to set it on every component in app.
But i want to set custom font on some of TextView in app.

Issue is when i set `fontFamily` in `AppTheme` then i can not set font or `fontFamily` on any `TextView`. But i can set that when i remove `fontFamily` and `font` from `AppTheme`. Here is the preview -

1. with font attribute in AppTheme style

[image: with font in AppTheme]

2. without font attribute in AppTheme style

[image: with font in AppTheme]

**Note:** I know either font or fontFamily can be used, i was just trying both if works. so please ignore it.

Comment: same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Tooto Did you try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/16407123/6891563

Answer (score 0):

Khemraj is correct in suggesting https://stackoverflow.com/a/16407123/6891563, because when you want to override some component's property you need to override its style, so when you add (taked from Hussein El Feky):

```
<!-- Into a styles.xml--!>
<style name="RobotoTextViewStyle" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-light</item>
</style>

<!-- Into a themes.xml--!>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/RobotoTextViewStyle</item>
    <item name="buttonStyle">@style/RobotoButtonStyle</item>
</style>
```

You are overriting all your TextViews' styles, so whenever you use AppTheme, TextView components will listen to RobotoTextViewStyle properties and use them.