# Setting custom font for Switch label

Tags: android, android-styles, android-fonts, android-switch

I've successfully set up app-wide custom font with the help of [Docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45978777/1181261). Basically I've made a new font style and referenced it in my `AppTheme`:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/custom_font</item>
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/custom_font</item> 
</style>
```

It is working, but not for Switch element labels. As user [lxx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16404820/how-to-set-default-font-family-for-entire-android-app/45978777#comment86511890_45978777) noted in the linked answer:

> This doesn't set the font everywhere... e.g. if you have styles that
>   derive from Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat, it's not used there.

I am not sure though this is the reason behind Switches not having custom fonts.

So how do I apply this custom font to Switch elements too?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the typeface of switch as below:

```
switchObj.setSwitchTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(), "custom_font.ttf"));
```

Comment: This works for me with `Switch` too, not just `SwitchCompat`.

Comment: I will upvote if you remove the implication that this doesn't work with `Switch`.

Answer (score 0):

for switch label text and XML type of font family:
`switch_view.setTypeface(ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, font_resource_id));`

note: font_resource_id = R.font_directory.font_file