# How can I change all the text files in Android Project?

Tags: android

I already developed my android project and decided to update the **text font** it contains more than 1000+ files, I want to give the same font to all the text in all the files. How can I achive this?

**android:fontFamily="monospace"** assume I need to apply this format to all my text.

Comment: using that in your theme might do it.

Answer (score 0):

To change your app font follow the following steps:

Inside res directory create new directory and call it font.
Insert your font .ttf/.otf inside the font folder, Make sure the font name is lower case letters and underscore only.
Inside res -> values -> styles.xml inside  ->  add your font @font/font_name.

Now all your app text should be in the font that you add.

original answer [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54696464/3790052)