# How to add typeface in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, android-layout, typeface

How To add typeface in eclipse so that we can use in our application.
     I have read that provided typeface in inbuilt typeface for android

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Typeface.html
Typeface Static fields.

Is there any way to add typeface here[image]

Answer (score 0):

I used my own font in the android application as follows,

Put the font file .ttf into the assets folder.

then create the object of typeface as,

```
mTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), ttfFileName);
```

And then set the type face to UI elements as,

```
findViewById(R.id.nameTextView).setTypeface(mTypeface, Typeface.BOLD);
```

Comment: My Question is **How could you set this typeface in xml like the image**

Comment: Directly through XML is not possible. You have to write custom component. Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973270/using-a-custom-typeface-in-android)