# Best practice to share an embedded font with whole project

Tags: android, fonts, typeface, android-fonts

I was wondering if it's possible to define an embedded typeface to use for all `TextView`s in a `styles.xml` file.

I understand it's not as embedded typefaces have to be set programmatically on each element.

The code I use to do so is the following:

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/myfont.ttf");
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
tv.setTypeface(tf);
```

Now I'd like it if I was able to create the font from assets once and for all in an `Activity`, an `Application` singleton or anything persistent enough so I can reuse it in every `View` definition to set the font on every element I want.

Any advice will be greatly appreciated!

[EDIT]
Any comment on Mao's solution's up/down sides will be very welcome!

Comment: Quite similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5185587/2636001. If you only have `TextView`s, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5185587/2636001).

Comment: Nice "trick". I like Mao's answer though. Works oob. Any comment on how stable his solution will be is welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare a public static variable (in your main activity) which contains your typeFace and instanciate it in the onCreate method.

```
public static Typeface tf;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(),"fonts/yourFont.ttf");
}
```