# How to develop a complete Malayalam app?

Tags: android

I am a beginner in android app developer.How can i create a complete malayalam app.I want to make each interface like button,text view..etc in malayalam.Please help me by give some suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use this.

```
         TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
         Typeface Malayalam = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "AnjaliOldLipi.ttf");
         tv.setTypeface(Malayalam);
         tv.setText("റമീസ് ");
```

Download the ttf file from [HERE](https://code.google.com/p/naaraayam/downloads/detail?name=AnjaliOldLipi.ttf) and put it in the assets folder of your Android project.

Comment: It shows an error while saving..., Error:Some characters cannot mappped using "Cp 1252"character encoding.

Comment: Try the edited answer now, Plz make sure "AnjaliOldLipi.ttf" file is in your asset folder.

Comment: yah sure.. im using the same..., but it can't able to save, it shows like malayalam word can't mappped.

Comment: In Eclipse go to Window -> Preferences, select General -> Workspace. From the Text file encoding dropdown, select UTF-8.

Comment: no brother.. yet i did't get wot i want, actually.. i have a word document, Which include both Malayalam & Arabic letters in ASCII character set, i want to see this data in my app when pressing a button 'Read More'

Comment: I not that much aware of it, But i think "NO", Plz refer this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973270/using-a-custom-typeface-in-android