# Android app in malayalam

Tags: android

I want to make an android app which use malayalam language(an Indian language). I found many code with typeface changed. When I tried to copy that code, eclipse is showing question marks instead of malayalam text.I can't copy any malayalam text in eclipse. Please help me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: The quwstion is answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25052431/how-to-develop-a-complete-malayalam-app

Comment: For more information read the comment of the question.

Answer (score 0):

change your eclipse editor to use utf-8 encode first

Answer (score 0):

You doesn't mention the error in your code, I assume that the problem with encoding. In this case you can change the text encoding to `UTF-8` by the following step.

In Eclipse go to `Window -> Preferences, select General -> Workspace. From the Text file encoding dropdown, select UTF-8.`

Comment: When I type anything in malayalam in the eclipse IDE, it is getting replaced by question marks. tv.setText("?????"); actually Iam trying to copy a malayalam text in setText method. But it is not showing. Please help me bro..

Comment: I changed the encoding to utf-8 and added malayalam font in the assets. But still it is not working :(

Comment: Plz try this solution bro, i dont know thins one is work for you just try .  In my case it showing malayalam default. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4522337/unicode-characters-not-displayed-in-textview-settext

Answer (score 0):

you have to change you eclipse encoding to utf-8 under the preference section,
**also very importantly** you have to **add** that **malay font in the assets folder of your app.** 
here's a link to get the font
http://malayalam.indiatyping.com/index.php/download-malayalam-font